# What I can use to highlight PDF?

Tags: pdf, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)

Is there a software like Mac's default viewer, that allows you to annotate and highlight PDF documents?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: Duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs

Answer (score 2):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) has support for highlighting and annotating PDF documents. Also see http://okular.kde.org/faq.php#HowcanIannotateadocumentandsendittoafriendcollegueetc

Comment: Thanks... I'd prefer to avoid loading KDE libraries only for that, anyway. No GTK program that I can use ?

Comment: unfortunately Okular does not have undo feature

Answer (score 1):

"Xournal supports annotation of PDF files through the Poppler library; PDF files, much like paper styles, are loaded as an immutable background image."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xournal