# What to use to annotate PDF (Highlight/Underline)

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)

In windows, I can use Foxit but on Ubuntu x64, what can I use? Foxit seem to only provide a i386 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) under [Wine](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEUQFjAA&url=http://www.winehq.org/&rct=j&q=Wine&ei=wfbFTczzAsbMrQeGsaHGBA&usg=AFQjCNG_GieVLJmWMq2dtLWRMyBttJA2Xw&cad=rja)

Another related question **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36696/foxit-reader-on-wine-runs-but-does-not-install)**

Answer (score 5):

You can use Xournal. Works on my 64bit system.

Comment: Xournal works excellent on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: It was very basic I suggest not to use it, awful!!

Answer (score 4):

The KDE default Okular (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular) supports highlighting, underlining and so on.

Comment: Okular really works well for reviewing and annotating files.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://www.mendeley.com/. They have a nice client with a reader that can annotate, and it's great for organizing your PDFs as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it keeps notes separately from the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the 32bit foxit on 64bit ubuntu by running the command `sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture <name of the file>.deb` in a terminal in the same folder as the .deb file.

In such a way, you will not lose the application you are familiar with and you won't have to endure running it through wine either.

Note: the linux version of Foxit does not support text highlighting!