# Foxit Reader on Wine runs but does not install?

Tags: wine, pdf

I am new to Ubuntu (from Windows). I tried installing Foxit Reader via Wine, the setup runs, but its more like just a splash screen then Foxit is open. When I try to open another PDF by double clicking, it says "File not found". Under `Applications > Wine > Programs` theres not Foxit. Have foxit installed incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that FoxIt have designed the windows version to act like its "portable" version if it detects the "setup.exe" running under [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20763&iTestingId=54887).

This means that it doesnt need to be 'installed'.  You can create a Launcher if you

- Right-click on your desktop.
- In the Command Line entry Browse to where the setup.exe was downloaded.
- Then amend the entry to look like the following:
  [image]

Similarly (if using Lucid or Maverick),

- right-click the menu in the top panel and choose the option "edit menu".
- Locate where you want to locate the new menu option and create the new menu option using the same Command Line entry as in the screen-shot.

If you want to use the Windows Foxit Reader automatically when you double click a .pdf file then the instructions are very similar:

- Right click the PDF and choose the option "Open with other application"
- Use the Command Line syntax as above but append \"z:%f\" i.e. it should look like:
  [image]

Remember to leave the check box "Remember this application.." ticked

Comment: No, I think u misunderstood me, I was asking my cant I associate say *.pdf to Foxit, I seem to always get File not found, I think I saw somewhere its because Foxit expect Windows style filenames "`\\`" but Ubuntu gives Linux style "`/`"?

Comment: ok - I've amended my original answer.

Comment: @fossfreedom, cool! but what does that snippet actually do?

Comment: The Z:%f fools Foxit Reader so that it thinks that it is loading the file being passed as a parameter from the z:\ drive.  In wine, Z:\ is mapped to your file-system.

Comment: @fossfreedom, I now used Ubuntu Minimal + LXDE. I tried the same thing but nothing happens theres no errors either ... any ideas how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @jiewmeng - not really, I dont use LXDE.  However, saying that, make sure you have samba installed correctly since wine does need that to browse your file system.  I do note that the latest version of Foxit (v5) doesnt seem to work very well.  You can still download the older version (4.3) from the website.