# Need a PDF editor that will let me highlight text

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I've looked in the Software Centre but no mention of highlight features for the various PDF edit software.

I've installed adobe reader 9 but it doesn't seem to have the option.

Does anyone know of a PDF editor/reader that will let me highlight?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: You're certain that it's not just that one PDF that isn't highlightable, right?  Not every PDF document is able to be used in a "highlight" feature.

Comment: try okular .It can highlight but its KDE based

Comment: And if you want to do have more features try [xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Evince in Ubuntu 16.04. Finally! \o/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) supports PDF annotations.

For more see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs/)

**Or**

Using wine you can use Foxit reader as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36696/foxit-reader-on-wine-runs-but-does-not-install). Foxit runs pretty well using wine in Ubuntu

### **UPDATE 2**

Foxit has released a [linux version](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/company/press.php?id=408). So no more wine required. Foxit has a good support for annotation.

**UPDATE**
You can also use [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) which provides highlighting and annotation support.

Comment: Okular worked great

Comment: Foxit is available for linux now. It handles annotations and highlighting pretty well. https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/

Comment: @brainbreaker Thanks for the info. Updated the answer.