# Is there a better way to redact a PDF?

Tags: pdf, gimp, imagemagick, editing

I had to print a couple of PDFs recently to send to someone, but I wanted to redact (black out) a couple small bits of text.

A quick google search didn't turn up any tools for this specific purpose, so I fell back to imagemagick & gimp:

- `convert document.pdf document.png`
- `gimp document-0.png`
- (use paintbrush to black out text)
- print redacted page from gimp
- print remaining pages from xpdf

The problem with this strategy is that the conversion process (from PDF to PNG or whatever other format) loses quality. I tried editing the PDF in gimp but it didn't work right away.

Is there a specific tool that permits redaction in this way? *(It doesn't even need to be "real" redaction -- I'm not sending a softcopy so "fake" redaction will work because the hardcopy can't be hacked to reveal the underlying text.)*

Or, is there a trick to being able to edit PDFs in gimp?

Comment: PDF is scalable, PNG is raster graphics, which is probably why there is quality loss in the conversion process. Convert to a scalable format instead, such as SVG.

Comment: @Anonymous: Nice idea, but not usable. The resulting SVG file is massive; I had to -KILL the viewer after 30 minutes and a GiB or so of memory consumption.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*(originally I recommened Okular but it didn't work as I expected)*

**1. Edit the document in a vector editor**

I was able to open a PDF file in **Inkscape**, draw a rectangle over a piece of text and print it out. Inkscape is a vector editor so no rasterization involved. Some fonts looked wrong though - probably because the document was created on Windows machine with fonts which are absent on mine.

**Note** that any method that does not involve rasterization is only acceptable if you're going to print the redacted document on paper and not distribute it electronically, as the text still can be retrieved from under blackouts.

**2. Increase the rasterization resolution when opening in a bitmap editor**

Regarding "quality loss" when opening the page in **Gimp**: you can directly open a PDF file in Gimp. It will be rasterized in the process. The amount of quality loss in the process is a matter of resolution you choose when importing - 300 dpi should give you a very decent quality (the default is 100).

You can also get good results with ImageMagick's `convert` command if you tell it to increase resolution:

```
convert -density 300x300 ...
```

Comment: +1 and accepted! Thanks for suggesting inkscape, it did a reasonable job (not perfect -- it lost a couple of (unimportant to me) graphic objects) -- but very reasonable). And the tip on `convert` was good too: the incantation I used was `convert -density 300x300` and there's no loss of quality.

Comment: +1 for mentioning GIMP can handle pdfs quite well

Comment: Warning to the general populace: the redaction methods here that involve retaining text suggested here (e.g. all the ones that avoid rasterisation) are **not** secure. Text can still be selected from under blackouts, or read from the source of the file. See for example http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/2706743/posts and http://hackaday.com/2008/08/01/exposing-poorly-redacted-pdfs/

Comment: Although the original question asked about sending hardcopy only, for which nonrasterizing methods are acceptable, downvoting since this answer does not clearly enough warn about the security risk when distributing the result electronically.

Comment: @JesseGlick: instead of "punishing" me for not addressing a use case not even mentioned in the original question, you could've just edited the answer. That would be more beneficial for the future visitors.

Comment: Agreed, retracting downvote since the answer now makes this clearer.

Comment: Using Inkscape works for producing redacted PDFs if you save each page of the redacted PDF document to PNG, and then open the PNG in Inkscape and save it back to a PDF.  Then you can use another application to join the PDF pages. Text in the resulting document will look slightly blurred in a PDF viewer.

Answer (score 37):

You can use Okular.

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

1. Open the pdf with Okular.
2. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> (or go to Tools --> Annotations).
3. Press <kbd>8</kbd>.
4. Highlight the text you wish to redact.
5. Right click the text, select properties, select the "Type" as "Highlight", press <kbd>Ok</kbd>.
6. Print the file to a pdf *(check "Force rasterization" to make sure the redacted text is removed from the resulting file)*.

Comment: Perhaps mention how to make the highlight black.

Comment: Okular can redact with any color (black) of these functions: text highlight, free hand line, and polygon links with inner fill. You can save the setting as your own custom annotation tool. Easily using it over and over. Then when you print the file to pdf you should "force rasterization" to ensure the redaction is not reversible. Okular Version 1.1.3

Comment: It's black by default, works with the latest Okular version.  Thank you!

Comment: The comment about forcing the rasterization should be added to the answer.

Comment: Tried okular and Xournal and am still not able to add a simple black rectangle to my PDF to blacken out stuff that I dont want people to see. On a mac this can be done in `preview` with two clicks.

Comment: it seems important to mention that this does not actually black-out the document... opening the pdf in inkscape easily allows to see the underlying text. For legal documents this is a big issue.

Comment: This is the answer, if you find F6 is doing nothing and the Tools->Review option greyed out, it's probably because of DRM which you can ignore by changing a setting in Okular, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/222544/okular-doesnt-allow-me-to-do-reviews-on-certain-pdfs/920625#920625)

Comment: @Alain, how about you just print the pdf to file after editing in Okular? Will that fully hide the content?

Comment: @crobar unfortunately, even if you print (print to file) the pdf after editing it with Okular, the resulting pdf file can still be modified with Inkscape to retrieve the original file.

Comment: Also, printing to image may make data uanvaliable, but also makes the document unsearchable, and probably makes it 10x its size. Ideally, a redaction solution should just remove marked sensitive data, leaving the rest of the document untouched

Comment: When printing to a file, it's essential to change the filename. Otherwise the file will be overwritten during raster conversion and become corrupted!

Comment: It's not clear what "8" is referring to - it is not a keyboard shortcut in v20.12.3 at least. Furthermore, using the print to PDF option does not respect PDFs with different page sizes, even when setting print scaling to None.

Comment: Ubuntu 2204 - `582 MB of additional disk space will be used` seriously?

Comment: Upvoted. I found that Foxit Reader works really well for marking up and redacting PDFs too. And, for repeat jobs with 4 identical sections, LibreOffice Writer works well. But, in all cases, I still must use Okular when I'm done to rasterize the images and fully sanitize them. I explain the whole process [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468508/327339). I wonder if there's a command-line tool to use instead.

Answer (score 14):

Basically what you are trying to do is highlight/annotate a PDF, but with some flexibility towards marker opacity and colour (you mentioned you don't need to censor/remove something, merely redact). Have you taken a look at answers here:
[How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs/1533#1533)

One of the highest rated answers recommends **Xournal**, which has not been mentioned here and would be my weapon of choice. It is a tool that allows you to make handwritten notes but has extra features allowing you to annotate a PDF. By default it'll save your annotations as a separate file but also allows you to export the annotated PDF as a new PDF. This should maintain the layout, fonts, etc.

With Xournal you'd choose "Annotate PDF", then use a solid black marker to mask the parts you want to redact, and "Export to PDF".

There are some stories on the internet suggesting that Xournal rasterises the text in the exported PDF (thanks for pointing this out, MHC). This does not seem to be true: with simple annotations, the text remains selectable and searchable and the file size does not increase by much (it increased from 205 kb to 220 kb in the example below).

To install, run in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install xournal` or just select it from the Software Centre

[image: Xournal interface]
[image: Resulting exported PDF]

Comment: Xournal is good but you have to know that it can only export raster PDFs meaning that all text and vector information is lost in the process. If you can deal with that then Xournal is the application of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @MHC. Xournal does *not* rasterise, see revised answer for more information.

Comment: I just tried it for myself and you're absolutely right. Sorry for the confusion. It had been a while since I had used Xournal and somehow I was left with the impression that the exported documents weren't true PDFs. Thanks for setting that straight!

Comment: This works well, but I couldn't find a clean way to redact information. I had to use the draw tool to scribble which looks very messy and lacks the professionalism I'd like. Otherwise, spot on with the export rasterizing the content so it can't be selected and discovered.

Comment: For real redaction, that replaces textual data with images, combine this answer with @balu's that uses ImageMajick's `convert` command.

Answer (score 5):

I am redact a lot of PDF files everyday, so I spend a lot of time thinking how to do it the best way.

For me the best way is split PDF in 1-page PDF file, next to edit with GIMP, next to combine it. I don't use imagemagick on all files (I do not use at all), so I don't loss text-layer on all pages, but only on redacted. Do not load the whole PDF file at once, because it causes memory exhaustion.

### Split PDF in 1-page files

Easily split PDF files to 1-page PDF you can by this bash function (put it in ~/.bashrc):

```bash
function pdf_split(){
    for file in "$@"; do
        if [ "${file##*.}" != "pdf" ]; then
            echo "Skip $file because it's not PDF file";
            continue
        fi; 
        pages=$(pdfinfo "$file" | grep "Pages" | awk '{print $2}') 
        echo "Detect $pages in $file";
        filename="${file%.*}";
        unset Outfile;
        for i in $(seq 1 "$pages"); do
            pdftk "$file" cat "$i" output "$filename-$i.pdf";
            Outfile[$i]="$filename-$i.pdf";
        done;
    done;
};
```

You can now enter `split_pdf file.pdf` to get a lot of PDF files.

### Redact files

But, now you need edit all this files. 
You can do it with `gimp original-filename-*.pdf`.
I suggest configure shortcut in GIMP (Main window->Edit-> Shortcut) to replace file (I use CTRL+R), blur filter (eg. CTRL+D), close file (eg. CTRL+W) and exit GIMP (eg.CTRL+Q). Remember to don't load in GIMP to many files at once, but GIMP as you about load after open, so you can use `gimp original-filename-*.pdf` on thousand files safe.

### Combine files

You can combine files easily with: `pdftk originam-filename-*.pdf cat output "new-file-anon.pdf";`

### Connect it all together

These operations are very repetitive and boring, so I connect it all in 1 script:

```bash
function pdf_redact(){
    for file in "$@"; do
        if [ "${file##*.}" != "pdf" ]; then
            echo "Skip $file because it's not PDF file";
            continue
        fi; 
        pages=$(pdfinfo "$file" | grep "Pages" | awk '{print $2}') 
        echo "Detect $pages in $file";
        filename="${file%.*}";
        unset Outfile;
        for i in $(seq 1 "$pages"); do
            pdftk "$file" cat "$i" output "$filename-$i.pdf";
            Outfile[$i]="$filename-$i.pdf";
        done;
        gimp "${Outfile[@]}";
        pdftk "${Outfile[@]}" cat output "$filename-anon.pdf";
        rm "${Outfile[@]}";

    read -p "Do you want open output file? " -n 1 -r
    echo    
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
            evince "$filename-anon.pdf";
    fi

    read -p "Do you want upload output file to Scribd.com? " -n 1 -r
    echo 
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        scribd_up "$filename-anon.pdf";
    fi
    done;
};
```

The newest version of this script is always accessible at: http://dostep.jawne.info.pl/it/bashrc

Remember to close GIMP (CTRL+Q) after all redaction to continue script.

In addiction it as me to open redacted files (I like read to check whether all) and as to upload to Scribd with my other script - [scribd_up](http://dostep.jawne.info.pl/it/scribd_up), so now I can redact a lot of PDF files very efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I remember one time me and a colleague had to find a way to edit a couple of pdf, We ended up using Gimp.
I will comment you the details ... we open the pdf directly with gimp (in a terminal)

```
gimp the_file.pdf
```

Once you are finished editing, we did not save the changes, instead of that we print in to pdf file ... That seemed to work ok.

Comment: For whatever reason, gimp refuses to allow me to make any edits to the file. I had to convert with imagemagick's `convert` first, then edit the converted file. (See accepted answer.)

Comment: ok, the solution of inkscape is valid. But I repeat to you The Gimp can edit pdf files directly. =D

Comment: Gimp seems to work with most PDF files, but the file I was using last night didn't work correctly. Inkscape handled that file properly.

Answer (score 3):

As a lot of solutions here recommend redacting / blacking out through annotations (which leave the original content in the pdf), I recommend rasterizing the pdf afterwards to truly remove the original content. (Don't be [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cpnwh6jwaA).)

Here's one way to do that which, at the same time, keeps the quality up and the file size low (at least in my case of a bunch of black/white pages):

```
$  convert -quality 100 -density 180 -compress zip notreallyredacted.pdf trulyredacted.pdf
```

Note: `convert` needs ImageMagick.

Note 2: `convert` does not preserve the contents of forms you might have filled out. In order for it to not get lost you might want to print the document "to a file" in something like `evince` first (or in whatever application you filled out the form) and *then* rasterize it.

UPDATE November 2023: I noticed that this approach works well when annotating the PDF with e.g. Foxit PDF Reader but not with Evince. In the latter case, the annotations won't show up in the rasterized version, i.e. everything will be visible again. This is quite weird because whether I annotate the PDF with black rectangles/text highlights using Foxit or Evince, the resulting annotating PDF superficially looks the same in the other PDF reader (Evince or Foxit) respectively. But ImageMagick seems to see different things.

Comment: Just added the permissions fix.  This answer should be combined with the Xournal one.

Comment: Rasterizing makes the document unsearcheable, and probably 10x its original size.

Comment: Sure but a cynic would say that's usually not your issue but someone else's. At least, you're redacting things properly and people won't be able to undo your redactions.

Comment: An easy way to test if you have rasterized correctly is to just run pdtotext and verify there is no text output.

Answer (score 3):

[Xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) is a popular variant of Xournal which has what you need. It is not available via the package manager (on Ubuntu 20.10), but a Github release can be built using CMake.

The build instructions [here](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/blob/master/readme/LinuxBuild.md) suggest the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libgtk-3-dev libpoppler-glib-dev portaudio19-dev libsndfile-dev libcppunit-dev dvipng texlive libxml2-dev liblua5.3-dev libzip-dev librsvg2-dev gettext lua-lgi
```

In Xournalpp you should then select the rectangle icon and, next to the pen colours, the paint bucket icon. You can then create filled rectangles - but they will be transparent. To make them fully opaque, select `Tools > Pen Options > Fill Transparency` and change the pop-up to 100%. (This is explained on the Github issue [here](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/issues/2105).)

Comment: There are far more easier ways to install it than compiling from source. There is a snap, a flatpak and a PPA

Comment: It also now seems to be included with APT since Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04): https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/xournalpp.

Answer (score 2):

Open the PDF with the free tool [PDF-Xchange PDF Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer). Black out the text to be redacted using black rectangles. Print. That will get you easy, high-quality "fake" redaction.

Comment: That appears to be a win32 tool. Let me know if I missed the link for the linux port...

Comment: The free portable PDF-Xchange viewer  will work with wine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me with wine. The inkscape and gimp solutions are only really useful for single page redactions.

Answer (score 2):

Use LibreOffice Draw for that quick editing that you are looking for. After you are done you can save it as LibreOffice Draw format or export it again to PDF format (`File`>`Export as PDF`)

[image]

To be able to import PDF files in to LibreOffice Draw you must first install the package `libreoffice-pdfimport`.

Install it via the Ubuntu Software Center ([libreoffice-pdfimport](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libreoffice-pdfimport) [image: Install libreoffice-pdfimport]) or via a terminal with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-pdfimport`.

Comment: Just drawing boxes over original PDF doesn't remove original contents. Any vector editing software allows removing boxes and accessing hidden content.

Answer (score 2):

[PDF Studio](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/) is a non-opensource and is software that requires purchasing.

In terms of this question, from version 8 onwards it has a manual redaction feature. Users can select a text object and redact it. The content is removed from the PDF and replaced with a black rectangle.

In version 9 coming third quarter 2013, redaction annotations and burning will be also available for images and shapes.

Comment: [Per the faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq#promotion), you should disclose your affiliation with the product you are promoting.

Comment: Even though this is likely more of a promotional ad than an answer I have to say that PDFstudio really is a great piece of software. It might be a tad bit overpriced but it's certainly the best PDF editing suite for Linux out there. Make sure to at least try their [trial version](http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/demo/download/) out.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to remember the correct incantation for `convert` you can use [pdf-redact-tools](https://github.com/firstlookmedia/pdf-redact-tools), a shell script automating the process of exploding a PDF into PNG images and merging them back together after redaction (using a tool of your choice e.g. gimp). It's conventiently [apt-get installable](https://github.com/firstlookmedia/pdf-redact-tools#ubuntu).

Comment: +1 It’s the product of Micah Lee and others from First Look Media (publisher of The Intercept). Its man page is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pdf-redact-tools.1.html) (for example) and some background information from the time around its release in 2015 is available [here](https://theintercept.com/2015/05/27/first-look-publishes-code-redact-documents-create-warrant-canaries/).

Comment: Converting all pages to PNG seems a little bit overkill. I just tried with a 40 page, 300 KB document, and just a tiny annotation in one of the pages became a 10 MB, unsearcheable file.

Comment: If you want to redact safely, you unfortunately can't get around converting to an image. If you just overlay a black rectangle, the text will still be available in the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

## Web Tools

Okay, if your document is really sensitive, you don't want it going anywhere before redaction. Here are some web tools that may have good policy. The thing with these, is they have businesses aimed at corporate clients and offer these services to showcase their SDKs. Make sure to read their terms of service.

#### Never leave the browser

https://pdf.online/redact-pdf

#### Leave the browser but they get deleted afterwards

https://freepdfredactor.com/

https://avepdf.com/redact-pdf

#### Other suggestions

If you find better tools out there, feel free to comment. We'd like to have a good list of what's available to us.

Answer (score 2):

### Redacting a PDF: draw black boxes over sensitive text or images using LibreOffice Writer or Foxit PDF Reader, then rasterize in Okular

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2.*

(Don't be scared by the long answer. This takes just a couple minutes once you've done it a couple times. I provide a lot of detail to make you understand the process the first time is all).

Redacting PDFs is a fairly common need for me, and after much trial and pain over the years, this is the process I've finally come to:

##### Summary (quick description)

1. Use Foxit Reader or LibreOffice Writer to draw black boxes over sensitive content.
2. Use Okular to print the resulting PDF to another PDF, with "Force rasterization" *on* in order to force-merge your concealing black box with the images underneath, thereby truly removing, not just concealing, your sensitive content.

##### Details (full, detailed tutorial)

1. **Install Foxit Reader:** https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/

   1. Note: this is the best PDF reader for Linux, in my opinion, for general use, as it allows you to take notes on your PDFs. You can highlight, draw, underline, strike through, take notes on, etc., PDFs.
   2. But, it's not open source. It's only no cost.
   3. Also, it is sometimes buggy. If it ever freezes for you, run `pkill -f foxit` to kill all open instances of Foxit Reader. This usually fixes it for me and I can then open it again. Sometimes the dropdown menus get stretched or put in weird places on your screen too. Drag it to a different monitor and it may fix it.
2. **Install Okular PDF reader:**

   ```bash
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install okular
   ```
3. **Redact your PDF by drawing black boxes over sensitive content.**

   1. **Option 1** (what I normally do): **use Foxit Reader:**

      1. Open your PDF in Foxit Reader.
      2. (Optional) Go to View --> Page Display --> Continuous.
      3. Click the "Comment" button at the top center to bring up your highlighting and markup tools (see image below).
      4. Use the "Highlight" button at the top left to highlight sensitive searchable text. Or, use the "Area Highlight" button at the top right to draw boxes to highlight sensitive text or images. Here is an image showing some areas of a PDF I've just highlighted to redact. I've circled the 3 buttons at the top, and my Foxit Reader highlight redactions are in yellow:

         [image]
      5. Right-click your highlighted text and go to "Properties" --> click the colored box and choose the black color, and set the "Opacity" to 100% (important, I think) to fully hide the contents underneath it. Also check the box for "Set Current Properties as Default" so that future highlight actions will use these settings. Here are my settings:

         [image]

         Click "Close" to apply this change to your highlighted text.

         Right-click your other highlighted section (ex: what you highlighted with the "Area Highlight" tool) and repeat the process.
      6. You now have both the "Highlight" tool and the "Area Highlight" tool configured to apply black, 100% opaque highlighting to cover up sensitive parts of your document. Use these tools to redact your document. Save as you go.
      7. When done, save the PDF with the save button in the top-left.
      8. Do NOT stop here! You still need to rasterize the document to merge your redactions with the content underneath, thereby stripping the original text and images.
   2. **Option 2** (what I do for redacting with many boxes in repeated patterns, such as on a W-2 US tax form): **use LibreOffice Writer:**

      1. Notes:

         1. This works well on W-2 tax forms because they have the same section duplicated 4 times.
         2. It's a bit of a pain, but this is the best way I've found for 1 or 2 pg PDFs, such as W-2s, where you need to repeatedly copy/paste groups of redaction boxes into multiple places.
         3. The benefits of doing it in LibreOffice Writer are that you can draw text boxes to redact sections, then multi-select them with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, group them with the right-click menu, and copy/paste more boxes in the event of redacting multiple similar sections of the document. This means you draw 20 or so boxes one time, then group them and copy/paste them 3 times (to cover all 4 sections of the W-2), rather than drawing 80 boxes (redoing the same pattern of 20 or so boxes 4 times).
      2. Follow my steps to convert a PDF to JPG images, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700520/4561887). Converting the PDF to an image removes all searchable text.
      3. Drag the JPG image into LibreOffice Writer. Resize it to fill the whole page.
      4. Draw filled rectangular boxes all over the text you'd like to redact.
      5. Multi-select (with Shift) and right click --> "Group" the boxes if desired. Copy/paste groups of boxes as desired, and move them with the Arrow Keys. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> for fine-tuned adjustments.
      6. Export as a PDF: File --> Export As --> Export as PDF...
      7. Do NOT stop here! Even though you just stripped all searchable text by converting the original PDF to a JPG image first, you still need to rasterize the document to merge your redactions with the content underneath, thereby stripping any *redacted image content* you don't want others to see.
4. **Rasterize with Okular:**

   1. Open up your pseudo-redacted PDF, which has opaque black boxes drawn all over it, in the Okular PDF reader.
   2. Go to File --> Print --> choose "Print to File (PDF)" as the printer from the drop-down menu --> click "Options" at the bottom-left of the window --> choose the "PDF Options" tab --> check the box for "Force rasterization" [VERY IMPORTANT!] --> set your desired "Output file" path --> click "Print". Here are what my settings look like:

      [image]

      Note that rasterization is *super important!* Rasterization is what converts the entire PDF into an image, which 1) removes searchable text from the PDF, thereby actually redacting your text if you used the Foxit Reader option above, and 2) blends your redaction boxes in with the images and text behind them, thereby actual redacting the image content left over behind your boxes from both redaction options above.

      If you hover your mouse over the "Force rasterization" check box in Okular, you'll see a little popup context window that says:

      > Rasterize into an image before printing
      >
      > Press **Shift** for more.

      If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the context window gets bigger and says:

      > Forces the rasterization of each page into an image before printing it. This usually gives somewhat worse results, but is useful when printing documents that appear to print incorrectly.

      Here is a screenshot of that:

      [image]

      The PDF you have rasterized and printed-to-PDF from Okular is now your final, redacted PDF you can share with others. But, before we do that, let's verify that is truly has been sanitized.
5. **Verify that your PDF is sanitized.**

   1. To verify that boxed-over text is gone, try to copy/paste text from it:

      1. open the final PDF in a PDF viewer and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all searchable text (there should be none), followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it. Then, open a text editor and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to try to paste any copied text. If you properly did rasterization above, *nothing* should paste into your text editor, because all searchable text is now only an image. If you skipped that step, you'd be able to copy and paste *all* text, even the text you covered up with black boxes.
   2. To verify that boxed-over images are gone, we are doing to *extract* the underlying images from the PDF. This is *not* The same as *converting* a PDF to images. For the latter, see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187844/327339). But for the former, which is what we want this time, see [@pl1nk's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/150106/327339). Here are the steps:

      ```bash
      # extract images from the PDF
      mkdir -p temp
      pdfimages -all my_rasterized_pdf.pdf temp/rasterized
      ```

      The above command will convert all images found in the PDF to their corresponding embedded image types, and store them in files like this:

      ```bash
      temp/rasterized-000.jpg  # pg1 as an image
      temp/rasterized-001.jpg  # pg2 as an image
      temp/rasterized-002.jpg  # pg3 as an image
      temp/rasterized-003.jpg  # pg4 as an image
      etc.
      ```

      Open each image and you should see only *sanitized* image content, with black boxes over the images and text wherever you drew black boxes over the images and text.

      As a comparison, run `pdfimages` over the *pre-rasterized* version, like this:

      ```bash
      pdfimages -all my_NOT_rasterized_pdf.pdf temp/NOT_rasterized
      ```

      ...and you'll see files like this, of whatever type their embedded type was:

      ```bash
      temp/NOT_rasterized-000.png  # embedded images within the pdf
      temp/NOT_rasterized-000.tif  # embedded images within the pdf
      temp/NOT_rasterized-001.png  # embedded images within the pdf
      etc.
      ```

      Open those images and you will see *un*sanitized image content, with *no* black boxes anywhere! You will see the full, original images.

      So, now you've seen what rasterization does, and that just drawing black boxes is *not* enough. You need to convert the PDF to a new image somehow to strip all text and underlying image data.
6. Done!

Lastly, if you want to **convert your sanitized PDF back into a searchable PDF**, get my tool here: [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF). Then install it like this:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF.git
PDF2SearchablePDF/install.sh
. ~/.profile
pdf2searchablepdf -h
```

Don't delete the repo you downloaded. The installed file is a symlink that links to it.

Use it to convert `my_rasterized_pdf.pdf` into a searchable PDF, like this:

```bash
pdf2searchablepdf -c my_rasterized_pdf.pdf
```

This will produce these 4 searchable files, which are *possibly*, but not always, up to 3 or 4 distinct sizes:

```
my_rasterized_pdf_searchable.pdf
my_rasterized_pdf_searchable_large.pdf
my_rasterized_pdf_searchable_medium.pdf
my_rasterized_pdf_searchable_small.pdf
```

**Size tests on a real file:**

Here is some real test data I just produced, so you can get a feel for how the PDF size will vary at each step:

```bash
# original 5-pg PDF file
# - generated from a LaTeX file using `pdflatex`, as I explain here:
#   https://askubuntu.com/a/1473017/327339
my_pdf.pdf                              # 139.5 kB

# after using Foxit Reader to draw a few black highlight boxes onto it
my_pdf_redacted.pdf                     # 141.9 KB

# After using Okular to **rasterize** the PDF via print-to-pdf with  the "Force
# rasterization" box checked
my_pdf_sanitized.pdf                    # 2.6 MB

# After using my `pdf2searchablepdf` tool to re-OCR the document and make it
# searchable again:
my_pdf_sanitized_searchable.pdf         # 1.9 MB, and looks good
my_pdf_sanitized_searchable_large.pdf   # 1.9 MB, and looks good
my_pdf_sanitized_searchable_medium.pdf  # 507.8 KB, and looks okay (very usable)
my_pdf_sanitized_searchable_small.pdf   # 170.7 KB, and looks **horrible**
```

### TODO

1. [ ] Find a way to rasterize from the command-line instead of using Okular, so that I don't have to use such a heavy GUI tool for such a simple step that could probably be automated.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this tool: https://launchpad.net/updf

Here it is (but anyway, the text is selectable):

[image]

Comment: uPDF is great in that it preserves the original PDF and its text and svg content. However, it appears to have some problems with compression levels. Edited PDFs are about 3-4x larger in size than the original. Thank you for posting this, though. I wasn't aware of uPDF.

Comment: Yes I know it has some problems, it's a bit rough. Hopefully newer releases will correct these issues... :)

Comment: As mentioned, uPDF does have a lot of bugs (and not even undo/redo) but everything still went well in my case, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to do this is to use http://www.pdfescape.com. You can annotate, add text and images, draw a "whiteout" rectangle around stuff you want to redact, and you can quickly download and save it. It also works really well with multi-page documents, which is something that lots of other solutions don't work well with. For example, if you open a multi-page document in Gimp or Inkscape, you will only be able to open one page at a time. The process is much faster in PDFescape. The whole process for me to redact a 2-page document takes less than a minute.

Comment: Does not truly wipe the data you painted over. (I can still search for it and it will "highlight" below).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple editors for editing PDF documents directly, such as `pdfedit`, or converter it to other vector formats that might be better supported, such as `pstoedit`. However I wouldn't recommend the use of any of them as the risk of doing something stupid, like just painting over the text with black while leaving the vectors in place is to easy, thus making the redaction trivial to undo.

Going the vector to bitmap route is the safest way, preferably the 1bit bitmap route, to avoid any potential issues with alpha channels or color differences that could leave the text readable.

If possible you should always redact the original document and just flat out remove the info, not the paint on the PDF, as even the kerning and spacing of text around the redacted text can give it away.

Comment: I understand the issues with redacting properly, but thank you for taking the care to point them out for anyone who comes along after. In my case, the PDF itself is disposable -- all I'm looking for is a hardcopy. (The PDF will be deleted as soon as I'm have hardcopy.) FWIW, `pdfedit` did not work: when I drew a black rectangle over the text in question, it nuked the rest of the page, leaving me with a document consisting of a single black rectangle.

Comment: Going vector to bitmap, while safe, it's pretty overkill. All text information is lost, searches are impossible, and a 100 KB file may become a multi MB file easily. A proper redaction tool, that actually removes sensitive info while leaving the rest of the document untouched, is the best way to proceed. Problem is it seems there's no free tool to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I add to the list: [Krita](https://krita.org/en/). Had no quality loss, because when importing PDF you can define dpi (set it to 300, as @Sergey said). After editing hit "Export as PDF". Lastly, I find Krita more intuitive than Gimp, after having been a long time user of Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I was very surprised that all the other answers involve jumping through various kinds of hoops (rasterisation, splitting/joining files, using special tools, ugh).

There is a simple tool called [redact-magic-paste](https://github.com/devkev/redact-magic-paste) that can be used to easily and directly convert the (to be redacted) text into a sequence of solid block "█" characters.  This means that the redacted text is gone - so the resulting file is safe to share digitally as well as print - while also avoiding the downsides of rasterisation (huge unsearchable files, splitting/joining, etc).

I recently used it to redact some PDFs, my workflow was:

1. Open the PDF in LibreOffice (which opens it as a "Drawing", not great but good enough for this).
2. Run the tool in a terminal.  You need to tell it the font (and size) of the text that's going to be redacted.
3. For each redaction, highlight the text to be redacted, then press Ctrl-C, then Ctrl-V.  The tool automatically and instantly converts the copied text into a roughly equivalent length of solid block characters.  So then when you paste, the original text gets replaced by this redaction block.
4. When you're done, print or export to PDF as usual.  Press Ctrl-C in the terminal to stop the tool.

Disclaimer: I wrote this thing (...because I couldn't bring myself to do the hoop-jumping).

Answer (score -2):

If using LibreOffice to create PDF file, open doc in LibreOffice , highlight text to be redacted, right click and select character, select Background and click on black. Export to PDF.

Comment: This doesn't remove sensitive information, it's still there and can be selected and copy-pasted anywhere. From version 6.3, LibreOffice comes with an actual redaction option, even if it's a little bit clunky (it rasterizes the whole document, involves sending it to Draw).