# How to Edit PDFs?

Tags: pdf

I typically have two needs:

Scenario A. **Change a single PDF page.**

In this case I have a PDF but not the original source file used to create the PDF. I don't want to try to recreate the document from scratch. I'd like to open the PDF and change a few things. A good example of this scenario: I was responsible for planning a big event at a campground site, I had a PDF of the site. I wanted to start with that document, highlight some parts, add some labels, remove some parts that weren't relevant.

or

Scenario B. **Combine PDFs or extract page(s) from a PDF**

This scenario usually arises because I want a single PDF deliverable that is made up of parts that are best created in different programs. In this case I have the source files for all the documents but they don't play well enough together to easily create a single PDF deliverable. For part of it, I may want to use Libre Office Writer. For another page I may want to use Gimp. Still another page I may use Libre Office Calc. I could use Writer as the master document and embed images or the Calc object into that, but for ultimate control, you can't beat separate PDF documents that are then combined.

**What are the best tools / processes for editing PDFs in Ubuntu?**

Comment: Care to add your answer to here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72920/is-there-a-better-way-to-redact-a-pdf and flag this for closure as a dupe of the first? You can also edit the title and the question a tiny bit on the other side. That will make things more consistence and make sure that the information is located on one place.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

LibreOffice Draw does not work for me as the fonts get completely messed up which then throws the formatting of the document off.

Here are three solutions that for me have worked consistently over the years.

### [PDF-shuffler](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdfshuffler.1.html)

I do a lot of combining of PDF documents (as in the Scenario B) and I find PDF-shuffler simple and convenient. I have also used it to extract pages out of a larger pdf document and it works well there too. The **PDF-shuffler** GUI is simple and it works consistently.

Edit:
PDF-shuffler is unmaintained and has been replaced by its fork PDF-arranger:

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

### [Gimp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp)

Sometimes for Scenario A you just want to convert the PDF into an image and then manipulate the image. If you don't know the difference between a vector graphic and an image, you probably want to convert to an image and GIMP does a good job of that. When you open a PDF with GIMP it will give you some choices about how you want to convert it. Pay attention to the resolution option. Choose a higher number for a larger file size and a more detailed image.

### [Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape)

The truth is, there isn't a super easy way to edit PDF files following scenario A above. That is because PDF is a universal format and some of the structure of the document is lost when it is converted to PDF. A simple example: if you take a 3 page report and convert it to a PDF you have broken the links between the text on each page. If you edit the PDF version of it and delete a paragraph on the first page the text from pages 2 and 3 won't automatically flow onto the first page. It would be much easier to edit that document in the original program used to create it.

But for whatever reason, you don't have the original document so you are stuck working off of a PDF. So set your expectations appropriately  when editing a PDF document following scenario A.

Once you set your expectations accordingly, you'll see that inkscape is the best tool for most jobs here. It will allow you to import a single page of the PDF document as an inkscape vector graphic. There will be a few things grouped together that don't really make sense, and you may have to change some fonts (assuming you don't have the original fonts installed), but really it is slick.

There is a learning curve to Inkscape but the truth is that you can't manipulate PDF without using some program with a learning curve. For my time, I'd prefer to invest that in learning Inkscape--a great application for creating vector graphics that can come in handy for lots of different scenarios--than I would in trying to figure out how to use a special tool just for editing PDFs.

Good luck

Comment: PDF Studio for Linux?

Comment: @ringø PDF Studio is not free.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal PDF for which LIbreOffice fails, let's find / open a bug for it and link to it. I've had some problem in the past I think too with some documents.

Comment: there is hardly a learning curve to wysiwyg [foxit](https://askubuntu.com/a/265189/16023).

Comment: Gimp was the best way to go. Libreoffice screwed up all the text in my pdf, that it was condensed and unreadable.

Comment: pdf shuffler is outdated and replaced by pdf arranger as mentioned in an answer further down on this page.

Comment: Pdf Shuffler is not maintained any more, however its fork Pdf Arranger is maintained and available in recent versions of Ubuntu: https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger

Answer (score 264):

**LibreOffice Draw**

This impressed me:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
libreoffice my.pdf
```

Just open the PDF, edit, and export as PDF.

The editing tools appear in a toolbar at the bottom of the window (took me some time to find it...)

Relevant feature set I have found so far (Ubuntu 13.04, LibreOffice 4.0.2.2):

- **Remove pages**: Right click on the page on the left page list > Delete page. See also: [How can I extract a page range / a part of a PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf/1424049#1424049)
- **Change page order**: Drag drop pages on the page list
- **Edit existing text fields** (edit text, formatting and position). Just click twice with the select tool to enter edit mode.
- **Add new text fields**. Choose the text tool at the bottom (T), select the desired text area, and write.
- **Edit non text fields objects** like lines or bullets.
- **Create fillable PDF forms** (Enable the Form* toolbars and be sure to select "Create a PDF Form")

I could not find an extremely convenient highlight method, but you could get away with editing text attributes like setting the colour red and boldface. I could not change the background colour tough.

If I missed good features, please edit and add them!

Here is a screenshot of me editing a PDF exported from this ODT: https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/f3497274fffcb043b9751c903c9fe715a5b023ce/test.odt on 6.4.6.

[image]

Of course, as you can see in the screenshot above, PDFs don't have as much information as the original ODT, and e.g. I can only edit one visible line at a time of a paragraph, and the following paragraphs won't "wrap back" to the correct size, since PDFs simply aren't designed to be editable.

**Note: I know that it fails for a few type of PDFs**, it has already happened to me.

If that is the case for you, please open a minimal, super detailed and reproducible bug report on their bug tracker https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/ so that devs may solve it, and post the link as a comment. When it happened to me I was lazy/inexperienced and didn't do that :-)

Despite this, it was still the best open solution when I last checked, and it works most of the time.

Comment: For "scenario A", LibreOffice pdf-importer (you might have to install it separately if have the Ubuntu pre-installed or the PPA), and for "scenario B" `pdftk` is the simplest (yet very powerful). Alternatively, for "scenario A" Inkscape in some cases.

Comment: if anyone knows, please add installation procedure, I installed long ago and I don't remember exactly how. I don't think I added the pdf importer explicitly tough, but I may be mistaken

Comment: If you are not installing the Community-provided LibreOffice (i.e., from libreoffice.org), you must do `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-pdfimport`.

Comment: Resulting PDF lost some elements, but libreoffice worked in a pinch, thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me; messes up the whole PDF, seemingly because it doesn't use the font info.

Comment: Doesn't deal well with fonts at all.

Comment: @Raphael a link to a bug report would be very welcome ;-) Agreed it is not perfect yet.

Comment: Impressive! Perfect to quickly fill in PDF registration forms.

Comment: Might work for some simple pdf files, but does scramble the one I tried. **Foxit**, however, (see answer below) works 1:1.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty if you can, open a bug report with your PDF and how it was generated. Cheers.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 Creator: **Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0)**, Producer: **Adobe PDF Library 9.0**. The document has two columns and is mostly just simple text (with a logo at the top). If I stumble upon a scrambly document which I can share I will. -- Basically the font size got bigger and the columns "overflow"...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty thanks! If you find a document that you can share and full generation details, put it on their bug tracker, and link on a comment.

Comment: took forever to load. I gave up, installed pdfshuffler, rotated the pages I needed to rotate and saved the changes before libreoffice had finished opening my file.

Comment: @craq thanks for the report, please create a bug report to tell the devs about that issue as well.

Comment: This completely sucked for me. Just trying to sign a document and it doesn't work -- in order to save the signature you have to export which saves a new layout for everything due to font issues, with all the words going off the page.

Comment: @6005 thanks for the report. Please open an issue upstream, and I'll link to it as it gets confirmed.

Comment: Screws up many fonts like others said.

Comment: It definitely has the required features, but I just tried to open a LaTeX PDF document with Libre Office Draw and it completely scrambled the formatting. All my LaTeX formulas and .eps figures are completely broken.

Comment: @EnteFetz provide example PDF and hopefully latex source :-)

Comment: I tried for about 5 minutes to just insert text: clicking on the text icon and then on the page made me select whatever I was clicking on. I could not find any place where to enter my text. I tried xournal next and in 5 minutes, I had filled every piece of text I needed to fill.

Answer (score 65):

You can use the latest version of [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/), which lets you edit all elements on the page.

Hint: Try the newest version first. But, as the last version 1.9.24 that I tried, had a bug that wouldnt open all images of a pdf file, the version 1.9.00 worked very fine, but the only way to get it is a direct link:
http://code-industry.net/public/MasterPDFEditor-1.9.00.x86_64.tar.gz
http://code-industry.net/public/MasterPDFEditor-1.9.00.i386.tar.gz

As mentioned in the comments, Master PDF Editor version 4, which was the last free version that did not put a watermark in the PDF, is taken down from its website, but is available at
http://code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-4.3.89_qt5.amd64.deb

Comment: thanks for sharing this. this is quite useful PDF editor.

Comment: It used to be free but now you have to buy it :) Can't deny the greatness of this tool!

Comment: Did I miss off something? The website reads: "The Linux-based version is free for non-commercial use."

Comment: I found this impressive straight away. Mainly because it got all the fonts and alignments right and looked exactly like the origional document. Well... at least it worked for me like that.

Comment: This is a full-featured professional application that can edit forms and save them (even in the free version).  The free version locks some advanced features, but isn't crippled.  Worth the price if you need the advanced features.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.  The program is professional complete and workable.  It handled my task with no problem.

Comment: Agree - this is the best choice for pdf editing and creating. And a free version for linux.

Comment: Master PDF Editor (v5) inserts a watermark ("Created in Master PDF Editor") in the free version, which makes it useless. You need to buy the full version (~USD70 + taxes) to avoid the watermark.

Comment: @JayDin Bought the full version of Master PDF Editor after comparing with other tools. This program is *really* professional and deserves to be purchased (imo).

Comment: @JayDin Install version 4: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/download-master-pdf-editor-4-for-linux.html

Comment: The last free version (v4) linked in the answer still works in 2021 on Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: The free version inserts a watermark. It also needs libsane (`apt-get install libsane`), and installs (in August 2023) as master-pdf-editor-5 (`dpkg -L master-pdf-editor-5`).

Answer (score 65):

I'm a little late in the game here, but recently stumbled across this question while googling it for myself. For what it's worth, I would like to recommend [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) for the first scenario.

It should be in the software center, or you can simply run the following from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xournal
```

Besides that, I'm going to second everyone else's recommendation for pdfshuffler and pdftk for the second scenario.

Hope this helps!

Comment: excellent, free PDF annotation software and if you have a touch screen you can even sign off your docs just like on paper!!!

Comment: IIRC, Xournal rasterizes everything when saving/exporting. Not always what you want.

Comment: The default pdf export significantly lowered quality (and file size). I found that by enabling Options > Legacy PDF Export before exporting, the quality is nearly identical to the original.

Comment: @Raphael it still preserves text and the file size was pretty similar, I don't think it rasterizes that much to be fair

Comment: I confirm that the current version (4/2021) doesn't rasterize its content, and works smoothly over Debian 11.

Comment: This also works great for touchscreen annotation of pdfs

Comment: I can't see any quality drop, in my case it's perfect for adminisrative documents, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 16):

I think that **PDF-Shuffler** is small but quite good app.

Info: PDF-Shuffler is a small python-gtk application, which helps the user to merge or split pdf documents and rotate, crop and rearrange their pages using an interactive and intuitive graphical interface. It is a frontend for python-pyPdf.

[PDF-Shuffler Web Site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/)

Comment: Agreed Vladimir. In fact I should probably revise my answer as well. I have actually started using PDF-Shuffler instead of pdftk for lots of simple stuff like merging two pdf files.

Comment: I was glad to verify that pdfshuffler is available on Ubuntu 12.04 and helped me to rearrange the pages on a horrible PDF I got by email with some pages upside down. Excellent!

Comment: Great tool. Worked perfectly for my need

Answer (score 10):

PDF-Shuffler, which was mentioned here, is very old and has some issues since it wasn't updated in a very long time (since 2012). To fix those issues and add new functionality, a fork was created, called [PDF Arranger](https://github.com/jeromerobert/pdfarranger).

[image: PDF Arranger]

PDF Arranger is a free and open source application for manipulating PDF documents, that can be used to merge, split, rotate and crop PDF documents and reorder their pages, using an interactive user interface.

PDF Arranger is available in Ubuntu 19.04 and newer, and can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

For older Ubuntu versions there's a PPA to install it (provided by [Linux Uprising](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/pdfarranger-merge-split-rotate-crop-or.html)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

Comment: You can not edit the pdf as the topicstarter wants to.

Comment: From the original question: "Scenario B. Combine PDFs or extract page(s) from a PDF". PDF Arranger does that.

Comment: It is an amazing small app which does exactly what it is meant to, and works with Ubuntu and Debian very well.

Answer (score 8):

**Foxit PDF Editor** (non-free) works well via **WINE**.

Newer versions of [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/editor/) might work as well -- haven't tested 'em, though.

~.~.~

ps: This answer applies to your "**Scenario A**": you can basically edit *everything* in a pdf with Foxit: i.e., you can not only add things, but actually edit them as if it were, say, a Word file.

Comment: In your opinion does it work better than inkscape which is free and  doesn't require WINE?

Comment: Thanks for asking! The truth is, I've never worked with Inkscape yet (as I thought it's mainly a vector-graphics-thing for professional or ambitious hobby designers). I'll give it a go for editing PDF's and will report back soon on how it compares to Foxit.

Comment: had a quick test-ride in **Inkscape**; looks pretty solid, with the major (?) [complaint/caveat/bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/183014) that [multiple-page support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170369) seems only possible with an [extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape-pages/), which has a 90 % upvote on sourceforge.net, so I guess it's sturdy. Would need to check that, too, for a fair comparison. Will report back.

Comment: [see also](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Multipage#Multicanvas_.28similar_to_multi-Artboard_on_adobe_illustrator_cs4.29.)

Answer (score 6):

There was magic thing called **pdfedit** in repository. Anyway, you can get it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/. I've used it to make some text changes directly to file, omitting any conversions, so that file structure remains untouched. Just choose text selection mode at toolbox and click the text you want to edit. You are allowed to do it through the text-box that appeares at upper-left corner of window. Of course, there are a lot more features.

Comment: Looks like the project has been abandoned - last updated in 2014-05-26.

Answer (score 6):

[**PDF Buddy**](https://www.pdfbuddy.com) is an online PDF editor that's a great solution for quick and easy cross-platform PDF editing, whether you're on Ubuntu or anything else. (It would come in handy for what you describe in Scenario A)

(Disclosure: I'm a co-founder of PDF Buddy)

Comment: i just tried BDF Buddy and it seems to be great for simple manipulation of PDF similar to scenario 1 or for signing PDF documents. Unlike inkscape you don't get any access to the PDF elements. But most of the time that's probably more trouble than it's worth. The "white out" feature pdf buddy has is usually sufficient for removing things.

Comment: The thing I didn't like was that you have to create an account (which I didn't do). I expected as much though from a freemium model which allows you to edit 3 documents for free a month. This is a great and easy solution for annotating an existing PDF or adding a signature.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use PDF Buddy to combine more than one PDF file.

Comment: Tested on one document, and it is great editor. Then spend an hour edit the real document, and realized it is not free :(

Comment: Found my way here via Google...as far as I can tell, PDFBuddy is primarily for *annotating*; it doesn't appear to allow actual editing (e.g of existing text content).

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that PDF Studio is not mentioned here.

It's an all-in-one PDF solution that can annotate, markup text, form fill, edit content, sign, OCR and manipulate PDF documents.

http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio

Comment: ...which is not free software, but I'm sure works just fine.

Comment: ...of all the non-free pdf editors I've come across, **Foxit** is still the benchmark for me... though I guess **Nitro** also deserves a mention...

Comment: PDF Studio Viewer is a free and can be used to annotate PDFs.

Answer (score 3):

**Scenario A**

After what seemed like an eternal quest to find a good solution for annotations, I found the superior alternative to be [PDF-XChange Editor](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) [via wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30820&iTestingId=85847). Everything I have tested so far works, just make sure you install it via the 32-bit .msi installer `wine msiexec /i path/to/msi_file`. Annotations are saved with the document and not separate (as in okular by default) and you can even edit document text with the free version (images with the paid one). Their forums are also linux friendly and they seem to try to keep it wine compatible. Running through wine is buttersmooth for me, but If you want a native app, I think master-pdf-editor is the most promising alternative.

**Scenario B**

Two command line tools that are shipped with Ubuntu by default, `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` is a fast and simple solution to split and merge pdf pages. If you want a GUI I recommend [pdf-sam](http://www.pdfsam.org/)

Comment: Installer problems doesn't seem to be reported anymore since late 1.7 wine versions. The other tools you mention instead are part of `poppler-utils` for the records.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 20.04 how to edit PDF**

I kindly suggest **Foxit PDF Reader for Linux**
which is free and beloved, nice to see it is available for Linux too

Download, install

Double click on a PDF and when asked, optionally set Foxit as default PDF viewer or just select Foxit for this **type on PDF** test

When the PDF is opened

Enable the *Comment* bar (there is a button for this between View and Connect buttons)

The comment bar will appear, don't be tricked by those new buttons, and instead

click on the three dots menu

There you have the nice *Typewrite* option

and there you are

Answer (score 0):

Considering a typical use case of editing a pdf document scanned using a scanner to delete some pages and to rotate pages libreoffice draw seems to be good enough. This is especially relevant if one is scanning a few pages of a bounded book.

To rotate a page by 180 degrees, right click on the document and press `flip horizontally` then right click again and press `flip vertically`.

Flipping once creates a mirror image and flipping twice rotates the page as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario B** - "Combine PDFs or extract page(s) from a PDF"

I'm surprised that **PDFsam** ("**s**plit-**a**nd-**m**erge") is not already noted in this Q&A. The ["basic edition" is free and open source](https://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/), and is also cross-platform. It can split, merge, mix, rotate, and extract.

I've used it for many years on each of Ubuntu (and other l*nux), MacOS, and Windows. Does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

[*Scribus*](https://www.scribus.net/) for editing PDFs. While clunky in usage, it does work, and to my experience is more faithful to the input PDF's layout than *LibreOffice Writer*.

```
# installation via apt package:
sudo apt install scribus

# installation via flatpak:
flatpak install flathub net.scribus.Scribus
```

Answer (score -1):

**'PDF-Shuffler' along with 'LibreOffice'**

You can download PDF-Shuffler from Ubuntu Software. With PDF-Shuffler you can Rotate, Crop, Delete or Export page/s. LibreOffice is already there as default.

Using these two Apps I could edit PDF in my Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

First, I opened the PDF file using PDF-Shuffler, **right-clicked and exported** the page that is to be edited (and named the new file). Then I opened that file using LibreOffice. Without doing anything I could edit that file.  Then I **saved** the file. As a result **I got an odg file**. Just double-clicked the file to open it. LibreOffice (LibreOffice Draw) opened that file. I got the new PDF file just by clicking on the red button for converting into PDF.

This was very easy. No need to pay money for Editing PDF as in Windows.