# How can I extract a page range / a part of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, split

Do you have any idea how to extract a part of a PDF document and save it as PDF?
On OS X it is absolutely trivial by using Preview. I tried PDF editor and other programs but to no avail.

I would like a program where I select the part that I want and then save it as a PDF file with a simple command like <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on OS X. I want the extracted part to be saved as PDF and not as JPEG, etc.

Answer (score 799):

`pdftk` is a useful multi-platform tool for the job ([pdftk homepage](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)).

```
pdftk full-pdf.pdf cat 12-15 output outfile_p12-15.pdf
```

you pass the filename of the main pdf, then you tell it to only include certain pages (12-15 in this example) and output it to a new file.

### Installation instructions:

To install the snap version, which is an unofficial repackaging of an old version of PDFtk (repackaged by Scott Moser), visit [this link](https://snapcraft.io/pdftk) or run:

```
sudo snap install pdftk
```

Alternatively, you can install an open source port of PDFtk to Java by Marc Vinyals, by running:

```
sudo apt install pdftk-java
```

Another alternative is PDFtk Server, available from the website: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/ . This version is free of charge for personal use, but it is not open source.

Comment: If I want to extract pages 1-10, 15, and 17, how do I write the command?

Comment: @PatrickLi `pdftk A=in.pdf cat A1-10 A15 A17 output out.pdf`

Comment: Note that `pdftk` is not available in Ubuntu 18.04. (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic)

Comment: @alkamid it is: sudo snap install pdftk

Comment: Although `pdftk` is certainly a tool that can do the job, I would recommend against it. This is not free software, but an clunky piece of shareware. Also it needs the JVM. A more reasonable tool is `qpdf`, as [suggested in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/672001/91549).

Comment: @leftaroundabout "PDFtk Server" (i.e. the command line tool `pdftk`) is free, licensed under GPL: https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-license/

Comment: Installing Java does not make sense for splitting a pdf, I agree with @leftaround.

Comment: To install `pdftk` in Ubuntu 20.04, I used `sudo apt install pdftk-java`. When I tried to run `pdftk` prior to it being installed, it told me how to install it. I believe it also said something like this would work: `snap install pdftk`.

Comment: Under Ububtu 18.04 it worked only from my home dir and after `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0`.

Comment: Here's my answer to show how to groups of separated individual or ranges of pages. Tested in Ubuntu 20.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/1318201/327339.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have Ubuntu 20_04 and `no Java` installed in `snap` nor in `apt list`, but pdftk works. How is that?

Comment: If you use the `A` to address pages, I think it needs to be uppter case, so `a` does not work.

Comment: ocular is supposed to be able to do this, but I don't see how.  It doesn;t provide any kind of menu for such things.

Comment: To further clarify earlier discussion, `pdftk` became open source in 2017, so it is now/again standard in GNU/Linux distributions. "pdftk-java is a port of PDFtk into Java[6] which is developed by Marc Vinyals and GPL licensed. The initial release was on December 30, 2017." (wikipedia).  It goes by the simple command line name `pdftk`.

Comment: This answer is notoriously limited in its usefulness because it doesn't generalize to multiple input  files. Here is an example using multiple inputs: `pdftk A=first.pdf B=second.pdf cat A1-7 B1-5 A8 output combined.pdf`.

Answer (score 376):

Very simple. Use the default PDF reader, select "Print To File" and that's it!

[image: print menu]

Then:

[image: setting new PDF]

Note that with this way, the text will no more be searchable, instead all texts are converted to images: this is how "Print" works.

Comment: Produces catastrophic results with beamer files, maps and any other documents that do not conform with the printer page format.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Just set the correct format under "Page Setup"

Comment: This can result in file with a much larger size than the original document.

Comment: @dat :  ِAlso, This can result in file with a much smaller size than the original document.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the case with all PDF viewers, but at least for firefox's internal PDF viewer and zathura, the resulting document is a *rasterized* PDF. This make you lose the ability to search text through the document and may imply that the final PDF has a larger size…

Comment: so it does not "extract" the page range. It creates a new pdf from the old one, as if you used high-definition printer/scanner pair.

Comment: Good for simple cases, but undesired results in documents with highlighting comments: the highlighting becomes 100% opacity and blocks the text.

Comment: Doesn't maintain OCRd text

Comment: Also doesn't preserve hyperlinks.

Comment: This effectively exports as an image, discarding basically all metadata

Comment: It turns text into images

Comment: It does not work for `qpdfview`.

Comment: Unnecessary double processing will destroy the original file, preserving only the content-pdftk is better

Comment: My texts are still shown up as texts after printing to file using Document Viewer (Evince) version 3.36.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I am curios as to where this outputs the newly created files. Even after having read the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-to-file.html.en#:~:text=To%20print%20to%20file%3A,once%20you%20have%20finished%20choosing.) it seems some things, like selecting where file will be saved aren't available for me. I am on using the default document viewer.

Comment: brilliant!  simple!  common sense!

Answer (score 288):

[QPDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QPDF) is great. Use it this way to extract pages 1 to 10 from `input.pdf` and save it as `output.pdf`:

```
qpdf input.pdf --pages . 1-10 -- output.pdf
```

This preserves all metadata associated with that file.

From the [old manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20210817225626/http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.pdf):

> If you wanted pages 1 through 5 from infile.pdf but you wanted the rest of the metadata to be dropped, you could instead run

```
qpdf --empty --pages infile.pdf 1-5 -- outfile.pdf
```

[Here's a link](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-selection) to the current documentation, giving more examples of page selection.

---

You can install it by invoking:

```
sudo apt-get install qpdf
```

It is a great tool for PDF manipulation. It's very fast and has very few dependencies. From [QPDF's GitHub repo](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf):

> QPDF is a command-line tool and C++ library that performs content-preserving transformations on PDF files. It supports linearization, encryption, and numerous other features. It can also be used for splitting and merging files, creating PDF files (but you have to supply all the content yourself), and inspecting files for study or analysis.

Comment: One of the best options, since qpdf is robust and doesn't alter (downsample images etc.) the contents of the PDF file.

Comment: The --pages flag allows you to splice pages from multiple PDFs. Note that you can avoid duplicating the name by using `.` in place of the input file in the --pages options: `qpdf --pages . 1-10 -- input.pdf output.pdf`.

Comment: Using `---pages .` doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe that was a recent addition?

Comment: When I extract only a few pages, why does the resulting PDF has the same data size as the source PDF?

Comment: Nice CLI answer I was looking for, just with the file size and `pages` option weird syntax.  TeXnologies won't help because I don't have the PDF source.  GS might be able to help since I've used that before to merge PDF documents past Preview.app's large shortcomings for my Mac, but I might have to do more research into that first..  I also don't see pdftk for Mac in Homebrew.  Ah, I see a gs answer below now!

Comment: If you want to extract pages 1-8 and 53-70 then `qpdf --pages . 1-8 . 53-70 -- input.pdf output.pdf`

Comment: `qpdf input.pdf --pages . 1 -- output.pdf` was not working for me. (version 8.0.2). This is what worked for me: `qpdf input.pdf --pages input.pdf 1 -- output.pdf`

Comment: In case you want each page be its own PDF file: `qpdf --split-pages big.pdf part_%d.pdf`. [Here's more](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/30#issuecomment-322019098-permalink).

Comment: This is indeed the best method! It is the only one which gave me a proportionally smaller file, instead of a bigger one, kept all meta data (qpdf has options for that - see manual), and also took ridiculously small amount of time - 8 sec for `qpdf` vs. 72 sec for `gs` and 300+ sec for some other methods

Comment: @Ash `--pages` takes it's own input file and the `--` is used to end the `--pages` parameters.

Comment: First option should work but doesn't, it only gives `.: read 1024 bytes`, second does work but it's a bit odd.

Comment: This doesn't seem to update the table of contents unfortunately, but otherwise great answer!

Comment: https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/129 -- related bug

Comment: qpdf worked perfectly for me in cygwin on windows, thanks! https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/qpdf.html

Comment: qpdf manual: https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: `--empty` didn't help much. Extracted a 36MB page out of a 48MB PDF with 47 pages all about the same size.

Answer (score 104):

### Page range - Nautilus script

---

**Overview**

I created a slightly more advanced script based on the tutorial @ThiagoPonte linked to. Its key features are

- that it's GUI based,
- compatible with spaces in file names,
- and based on three different backends that are capable of preserving all attributes of the original file

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# TITLE:        PDFextract
#
# AUTHOR:       (c) 2013-2015 Glutanimate (https://github.com/Glutanimate)
#
# VERSION:      0.2
#
# LICENSE:      GNU GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
# 
# OVERVIEW:     PDFextract is a simple PDF extraction script based on Ghostscript/qpdf/cpdf.
#               It provides a simple way to extract a page range from a PDF document and is meant
#               to be used as a file manager script/addon (e.g. Nautilus script).
#
# FEATURES:     - simple GUI based on YAD, an advanced Zenity fork.
#               - preserves _all_ attributes of your original PDF file and does not compress 
#                 embedded images further than they are.      
#               - can choose from three different backends: ghostscript, qpdf, cpdf
#
# DEPENDENCIES: ghostscript/qpdf/cpdf poppler-utils yad libnotify-bin
#                         
#               You need to install at least one of the three backends supported by this script.
#
#               - ghostscript, qpdf, poppler-utils, and libnotify-bin are available via 
#                 the standard Ubuntu repositories
#               - cpdf is a commercial CLI PDF toolkit that is free for personal use.
#                 It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries
#               - yad can be installed from the webupd8 PPA with the following command:
#                 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager && apt-get update && apt-get install yad
#
# NOTES:        Here is a quick comparison of the advantages and disadvantages of each backend:
#
#                               speed     metadata preservation     content preservation        license
#               ghostscript:     --               ++                         ++               open-source
#               cpdf:             -               ++                         ++               proprietary
#               qpdf:            ++                +                         ++               open-source
#
#               Results might vary depending on the document and the version of the tool in question.
#
# INSTALLATION: https://askubuntu.com/a/236415
#
# This script was inspired by Kurt Pfeifle's PDF extraction script 
# (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-extract-pages-pdf)
#
# Originally posted on askubuntu
# (https://askubuntu.com/a/282453)

# Variables

DOCUMENT="$1"
BACKENDSELECTION="^qpdf!ghostscript!cpdf"

# Functions

check_input(){
  if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    notify "Error: No input file selected."
    exit 1
  elif [[ ! "$(file -ib "$1")" == *application/pdf* ]]; then
    notify "Error: Not a valid PDF file."
    exit 1
  fi
}

check_deps () {
  for i in "$@"; do
    type "$i" > /dev/null 2>&1 
    if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
      MissingDeps+="$i"
    fi
  done
}

ghostscriptextract(){
  gs -dFirstPage="$STARTPAGE "-dLastPage="$STOPPAGE" -sOutputFile="$OUTFILE" -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTING=/default -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompressFonts=true -c \
  ".setpdfwrite << /EncodeColorImages true /DownsampleMonoImages false /SubsetFonts true /ASCII85EncodePages false /DefaultRenderingIntent /Default /ColorConversionStrategy \
  /LeaveColorUnchanged /MonoImageDownsampleThreshold 1.5 /ColorACSImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.4 /Blend 1 >> /GrayACSImageDict \
  << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.4 /Blend 1 >> /PreserveOverprintSettings false /MonoImageResolution 300 /MonoImageFilter /FlateEncode \
  /GrayImageResolution 300 /LockDistillerParams false /EncodeGrayImages true /MaxSubsetPCT 100 /GrayImageDict << /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor \
  0.4 /Blend 1 >> /ColorImageFilter /FlateEncode /EmbedAllFonts true /UCRandBGInfo /Remove /AutoRotatePages /PageByPage /ColorImageResolution 300 /ColorImageDict << \
  /VSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /HSamples [ 1 1 1 1 ] /QFactor 0.4 /Blend 1 >> /CompatibilityLevel 1.7 /EncodeMonoImages true /GrayImageDownsampleThreshold 1.5 \
  /AutoFilterGrayImages false /GrayImageFilter /FlateEncode /DownsampleGrayImages false /AutoFilterColorImages false /DownsampleColorImages false /CompressPages true \
  /ColorImageDownsampleThreshold 1.5 /PreserveHalftoneInfo false >> setdistillerparams" -f "$DOCUMENT"
}

cpdfextract(){
  cpdf "$DOCUMENT" "$STARTPAGE-$STOPPAGE" -o "$OUTFILE"
}

qpdfextract(){
  qpdf --linearize "$DOCUMENT" --pages "$DOCUMENT" "$STARTPAGE-$STOPPAGE" -- "$OUTFILE"
  echo "$OUTFILE"
  return 0 # even benign qpdf warnings produce error codes, so we suppress them
}

notify(){
  echo "$1"
  notify-send -i application-pdf "PDFextract" "$1"
}

dialog_warning(){
  echo "$1"
  yad --center --image dialog-warning \
  --title "PDFExtract Warning" \
  --text "$1" \
  --button="Try again:0" \
  --button="Exit:1"

  [[ "$?" != "0" ]] && exit 0
}

dialog_settings(){
  PAGECOUNT=$(pdfinfo "$DOCUMENT" | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//') #determine page count

  SETTINGS=($(\
      yad --form --width 300 --center \
          --window-icon application-pdf --image application-pdf \
          --separator=" " --title="PDFextract"\
          --text "Please choose the page range and backend"\
          --field="Start:NUM" 1[!1..$PAGECOUNT[!1]] --field="End:NUM" $PAGECOUNT[!1..$PAGECOUNT[!1]] \
          --field="Backend":CB "$BACKENDSELECTION" \
          --button="gtk-ok:0" --button="gtk-cancel:1"\
      ))

  SETTINGSRET="$?"

  [[ "$SETTINGSRET" != "0" ]] && exit 1

  STARTPAGE=$(printf %.0f ${SETTINGS[0]}) #round numbers and store array in variables
  STOPPAGE=$(printf %.0f ${SETTINGS[1]})
  BACKEND="${SETTINGS[2]}"
  EXTRACTOR="${BACKEND}extract"

  check_deps "$BACKEND"

  if [[ -n "$MissingDeps" ]]; then
    dialog_warning "Error, missing dependency: $MissingDeps"
    unset MissingDeps
    dialog_settings
    return
  fi

  if [[ "$STARTPAGE" -gt "$STOPPAGE" ]]; then 
    dialog_warning "<b>   Start page higher than stop page.   </b>"
    dialog_settings
    return
  fi

  OUTFILE="${DOCUMENT%.pdf} (p${STARTPAGE}-p${STOPPAGE}).pdf"
}

extract_pages(){
  $EXTRACTOR
  EXTRACTORRET="$?"
  if [[ "$EXTRACTORRET" = "0" ]]; then
    notify "Pages $STARTPAGE to $STOPPAGE succesfully extracted."
  else
    notify "There has been an error. Please check the CLI output."
  fi
}


# Main

check_input "$1"
dialog_settings
extract_pages
```

**Installation**

Please follow the [generic installation instructions for Nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-do-i-install-a-nautilus-script/236415#236415). Make sure to read the script header carefully as it will help to clarify the installation and usage of the script.

---

### Partial pages - PDF Arranger

---

**Overview**

> PDF Arranger is a small python-gtk application, which helps the user to merge or split pdf documents and rotate, crop and rearrange their pages using an interactive and intuitive graphical interface. It is a frontend for python-pyPdf.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

**Usage**

PDF Arranger can crop and delete single PDF pages. You can use it to extract a page range from a document or even partial pages using the cropping function:

[image]

---

### Page elements - Inkscape

---

**Overview**

Inkscape is a very powerful open-source vector graphics editor. It supports a wide range of different formats, including PDF files. You can use it to extract, modify and save page elements from a PDF file.

**Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

**Usage**

**1.)** Open the PDF file of your choice with Inkscape. An import dialog will appear. Choose the page you want to extract elements from. Leave the other settings as they are:

[image]

**2.)** In Inkscape click and drag to select the element(s) you want to extract:

[image]

**3.)** Invert the selection with <kbd>!</kbd> and delete the selected object with <kbd>DELETE</kbd>:

[image]

**4.)** Crop the document to the remaining objects by accessing the *Document Properties* dialog with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and selecting "fit document to image":

[image]

**5.)** Save the document as a PDF file from the *File* --> *Save as* dialog:

[image]

**6.)** If there are bitmap/raster images in your cropped document you can set their DPI in the dialog that appears next:

[image]

**7.)** If you followed all steps you will have produced a true PDF file that only consists of the objects of your choice:

[image]

Comment: Great effort. Thanks! I understand that it does not allow to select a _portion_ of a page, but only whole pages. Am I right?

Comment: @carnendil : Yes, exactly. I don't think ghostscript is capable of that. But [there might be other solutions out there to do this programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986876/extract-a-region-of-a-pdf-page-by-coordinates). For now I have edited my answer with an alternate (and a bit hackish) solution using PDF-shuffler.

Comment: `pdfshuffler` is not sufficient if you want to extract a part of the PDF page. The original PDF data of the page is still preserved in the file. Do not use this method if you want to remove sensitive data from a PDF file.

Comment: `pdfshuffler` is now called `pdfarranger`.

Comment: Just tried the first option "Page range - Nautilus script" and it totally works on Ubuntu 20.04, well done!

Comment: I wish you would have posted the three answers separately so that we could comment on each one separately and upvote them all separately.

Answer (score 70):

Save this as a shell script, like pdfextractor.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this function uses 3 arguments:
#     $1 is the first page of the range to extract
#     $2 is the last page of the range to extract
#     $3 is the input file
#     output file will be named "inputfile_pXX-pYY.pdf"
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
   -dFirstPage="${1}" \
   -dLastPage="${2}" \
   -sOutputFile="${3%.pdf}_p${1}-p${2}.pdf" \
   "${3}"
```

To run type:

```
./pdfextractor.sh 4 20 myfile.pdf
```

1. `4` refers to the page it will start the new pdf.
2. `20` refers to the page it will end the pdf with.
3. `myfile.pdf` is the pdf file you want to extract parts.

The output would be `myfile_p4_p20.pdf` in the same directory the original pdf file.

All this and more information here: [Tech Tip](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-extract-pages-pdf)

Comment: Let's keep it simple: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=10 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`

Comment: @Ho1 please write it as a new answer, it really helps!

Comment: This is the most portable answer, as ghostscript is likely to be installed pretty much anywhere.

Comment: `gs` is slightly familiar and much smaller file size than what qpdf gives!  pdftk is also not available on my Mac through Homebrew and I hear it's slow too.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 53):

In any system that a TeX distribution is installed:

```
pdfjam <input file> <page ranges> -o <output file>
```

For example:

```
pdfjam original.pdf 5-10 -o out.pdf
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79626/8666

Comment: this was the only one that worked for me .

Comment: Completely messed up my landscape PDF.

Comment: This used to work fine for me with landscape PDF's, but it's messing it up now.

Comment: Keeping it simple, but flexible, you can also do the following: `pdfjam original.pdf 2-` or `pdfjam original.pdf -4` depending on if you want from the 2nd page to the end, or only until the 4th page, respectively. It will automatically name the output based on input parameters (pages asked for).

Comment: `pdfjam --landscape ...` solves the landscape problem

Comment: The only solution I tried that accepted more than one range, e.g. `pdfjam original.pdf 2-4,43,49-64 -o selection.pdf`.

Answer (score 47):

There is a command line utility called **pdfseparate**.

From the docs:

```
pdfseparate sample.pdf sample-%d.pdf

extracts  all pages from sample.pdf, if i.e. sample.pdf has 3 pages, it
   produces

sample-1.pdf, sample-2.pdf, sample-3.pdf
```

Or, to select a single page (in this case, the first page) from the file sample.pdf:

```
pdfseparate -f 1 -l 1 sample.pdf sample-1.pdf
```

Comment: great tool! much faster than `pdftk`

Comment: Good, but it is only limited to one page, and if you want more than that, you will get separate pages.

Comment: Sure, though one can follow the above command with pdfunite to produce a single document.

Comment: If you have a huge document and need to split all pages, it is really fast and useful.

Comment: This is not the best method. It took 3m15s to `pdfseparate`+`pdfunite` a page range (1m11s for `gs` and 0m8s for `qpdf`), and also created a much bigger file (due to metadata for each SEPARATE page) - 62 MB vs. 37 MB original (for pages 81-end of 530), vs. 50 MB for `gs` and, properly, 33 MB for `qpdf` for same page range... Use `qpdf` instead!

Comment: I don't know how this tool works but out of one 48MB PDF file with 46 pages, it created 46 PDFs around 35MB each (!)

Comment: YMMV, but for me, I split the first page from a 766K file, which resulted in a 407K file (makes sense, since there was a lot of text, and an embedded image, whereas the rest of the file was mostly (probably) vector shapes), and when I added it to another 889K file with pdfunite, the result was 1.3M.

Answer (score 19):

`pdftk` (`sudo apt-get install pdftk`) is a great command line too for PDF manipulation. Here are some examples of what `pdftk` can do:

```
   Collate scanned pages
     pdftk A=even.pdf B=odd.pdf shuffle A B output collated.pdf
     or if odd.pdf is in reverse order:
     pdftk A=even.pdf B=odd.pdf shuffle A Bend-1 output collated.pdf

   Join in1.pdf and in2.pdf into a new PDF, out1.pdf
     pdftk in1.pdf in2.pdf cat output out1.pdf
     or (using handles):
     pdftk A=in1.pdf B=in2.pdf cat A B output out1.pdf
     or (using wildcards):
     pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf

   Remove page 13 from in1.pdf to create out1.pdf
     pdftk in.pdf cat 1-12 14-end output out1.pdf
     or:
     pdftk A=in1.pdf cat A1-12 A14-end output out1.pdf

   Burst a single PDF document into pages and dump its data to
   doc_data.txt
     pdftk in.pdf burst

   Rotate the first PDF page to 90 degrees clockwise
     pdftk in.pdf cat 1east 2-end output out.pdf

   Rotate an entire PDF document to 180 degrees
     pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endsouth output out.pdf
```

In your case, I would do:

```
     pdftk A=input.pdf cat A<page_range> output output.pdf
```

Comment: Package 'pdftk' has no installation candidate

Comment: This comment (with 40+ upvotes) [recommends against pdftk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf#comment1798509_282455)

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to do the same. All you have to do is:

1. install `pdftk`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pdftk
   ```
2. if you want to extract random pages:

   ```
   pdftk myoldfile.pdf cat 1 2 4 5 output mynewfile.pdf
   ```
3. if you want to extract a range:

   ```
   pdftk myoldfile.pdf cat 1-2 4-5 output mynewfile.pdf
   ```

Please check [the source](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.ch/2013/02/splitting-up-is-easy-for-pdf-file.html) for more infos.

Comment: I find this answer best because it shows how you can input multiple ranges.

Comment: This comment (with 40+ upvotes) [recommends against pdftk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf#comment1798509_282455)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried PDF Mod?

You can for example.. extract pages and save them as pdf.

**Description:**

*PDF Mod is a simple tool for modifying PDF documents. It can rotate, extract, remove 
and reorder pages via drag and drop. Multiple documents may be combined via drag
and drop. You may also edit the title, subject, author and keywords of a PDF
 document using PDF Mod.*

```
sudo apt install pdfmod
```

[image: Screenshot]

Hope this will useful.

Regars.

Comment: YES, I actually did try it but it does NOT allow me to save part of a page e.g. a plot as pdf... Unless I dont see the option. It allows me to extract a whole page from a document but that is not what I want

Comment: I use it regularly, great tool! but I had a document with about 170 pages that pdfmod could not handle.

Comment: Wow. This is surprisingly smooth. Threw my 512 page real book at it (50MiB) and it... was prompt. UI is a breeze. For a CLI junkie like me it takes some level of GUI to convince me, but this will do!

Comment: PDF Mod has bugs running in Kubuntu 18

Comment: Couldn't open a PDF generated by TurboTax.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to use inbuilt bash commands then [pdfseparate](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdfseparate.1.html) and [pdfunite](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdfunite.1.html) are for you.

```
pdfseparate sample.pdf sample-%d.pdf
# ls; sample.pdf sample-1.pdf sample-2.pdf sample-3.pdf sample-4.pdf

pdfunite sample-2.pdf sample-3.pdf output.pdf
# now you can use output.pdf
```

Comment: `pdfseparate` is not a "built-in bash command". Try `file $(which pdfseparate)`.

Comment: `pdfseparate` + `pdfunite` the parts, created an output file 3x bigger than the original file.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, I can do it with `imagemagick`. If you don't have it, install simply with:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

---

**Note 1**:
I've tried this with a one-page pdf (I'm learning to use `imagemagick`, so I didn't want more trouble than necessary). I don't know if/how it will work with multiple pages, but you can extract one page of interest with `pdftk`:

```
pdftk A=myfile.pdf cat A1 output page1.pdf
```

where you indicate the page number to be split out (in the example above, `A1` selects the first page).

**Note 2**:
The resulting image using this procedure will be a raster.

---

Open the pdf with the command `display`, which is part of the `imagemagick` suite:

```
display file.pdf
```

Mine looked like this:

[image: imagemagick display of a pdf]

<sup>Click on the image to see a full resolution version</sup>

Now you click on the window and a menu will pop to the side. There, select **Transform** | **Crop**.

[image: imagemagick transform>crop menu]

Back in the main window, you can select the area you want to crop by simply dragging the pointer (classic corner-to-corner selection).

[image: selection of area to crop]

<sup>Notice the hand-shaped pointer around the image while selecting</sup>

This selection can be refined before proceeding to the next step.

Once you are done, take notice of the little rectangle that appears on the upper left corner (see the image above). It shows the dimensions of the area selected first (e.g. `281x218`) and second the coordinates of the first corner (e.g. `+256+215`).

Write down the dimensions of the selected area; you'll need it at the moment of saving the cropped image.

Now, back at the pop menu (which now is the specific "crop" menu), click the button **Crop**.

[image: imagemagick crop menu]

Finally, once you are satisfied with the results of cropping, click on menu **File** | **Save**

Navigate to the folder where you want to save the cropped pdf, type a name, click the button **Format**, on the "Select image format type" window select **PDF** and click the button **Select**. Back on the "Browse and select a file" window, click the button **Save**.

[image: imagemagick save as pdf]

Before saving, `imagemagick` will ask to "select page geometry". Here, you type the dimensions of your cropped image, using a simple letter "x" to separate width and height.

[image: imagemagick select page geometry]

Now, you can do all this perfectly from the command line (the command is `convert` with option `-crop`) -- surely it's faster, but you would have to know beforehand the coordinates of the image you want to extract. Check `man convert` and [an example in their webpage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop).

Comment: DIdn't know about imagemagick's GUI. Looks interesting. However, please correct me if I'm wrong but I think imagemagick can't handle vectorized images. So what you're exporting is likely going to be a raster/bitmap image only. In that case this method is the same as taking taking a screenshot of a region of the document.

Comment: Indeed, `imagemagick` works only raster images, and `display` is just one command of the suite. There are plenty of interfaces for `imagemagick` -- check their webpage. For vector images the best solution is, I think, your method with Inkscape.

Comment: You might want to add a disclaimer at the top of the answer as a caution that this will convert from vector to raster graphics. This property makes it a fundamentally different approach.

Answer (score 6):

[mutool](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-clean.html), which comes with mupdf, can do a lot of simple PDF processing stuff, but has a more elegant syntax than `qpdf` (and some of the other answers). Additionally, it seems faster on big PDFs:

```bsh
# extract page range 20-40
mutool clean in.pdf out.pdf 20-40
# extract from all over the pdf
mutool clean in.pdf out.pdf '1, 3-4, 74-92'
```

Comment: Generates bigger files

Answer (score 5):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with `pdftk --version` 3.0.9 from May 11, 2018 (date shown at the bottom of `man pdftk`).

If using `pdftk`, here's how to format it for multiple groups of pages:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 13 18 33-36 39-41 52 output out.pdf
```

This will capture those groups of pages, inclusive.

To install and/or update `pdftk`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pdftk
```

### Related:

1. [my answer] How to rotate PDF pages: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394065/command-line-how-do-you-rotate-a-pdf-file-90-degrees/634882#634882

Answer (score 3):

PDF Split and Merge is quite useful for this and other PDF manipulation operations.

Download from   [here](http://www.pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/)

Comment: You can download the latest version from the link above, but if you prefer the convenience of the Software Center, you can also install it from there (or from the terminal, through `sudo apt-get install pdfsam`). However, the version in Ubuntu is quite outdated, as [it's still in version 1.1.4](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/pdfsam/) whereas the sourceforge version is already 2.2.2.

Comment: The latest 3.x (currently 3.1.0) has a [.deb package](http://www.pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/) that can be installed on Ubuntu and has an Extract Pages module that does what the OP asked

Comment: @Andrea Vacondio Bravo for your excellent edit! You're helping to make the internet safe. I found out that the file from the old link at sourceforge.net has crap embedded in it . The new owners of the SourceForge website said they were going to stop doing this, but obviously they lied.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Ubuntu do no provide command to do that directly.

But you can use [pdfseparate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdfseparate.1.html) and [pdfunite](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdfunite.1.html) in conjonction (both comes by default with your Ubuntu)

So if you want to extract page `32` to `65` of `sourcefile.pdf` in a new file called `extract.pdf`, you can type these commands :

```
mkdir tmppdfdir
pdfseparate -f 32 -l 65 sourcefile.pdf tmppdfdir/page-%d.pdf
pdfunite tmppdfdir/page*.pdf extract.pdf
rm -rf tmppdfdir/
```

Warning : Be sure that `tmppdfdir` do not already exists before !

Comment: This answer duplicates [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213054/116961), which was given 7+ months earlier. We already have way too many answers for this question. Please consider deleting this one. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Dan This is not a duplicate as the answer you point is only for extracting 2 pages from a 5 pages document. 
Unusable with 33 pages as in my answer. Mine is generic, the other not.
Remember that some documents have more than 500 pages.

Answer (score 2):

**LibreOffice Draw**

LibreOffice [is able to edit PDFs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs/288020#288020) and create new ones, and that allows you to easily and interactively select page ranges with your mouse.

This way you can easily inspect which pages you want visually and then immediately move them around without having to note the page number and go to the command line.

Another advantage is that almost every Linux desktop user is already going to have the fundamental LibreOffice package already installed in their computer, but if for some reason you don't:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Then, just open the PDF, e.g. from the CLI:

```
libreoffice raymond.pdf
```

or just open LibreOffice from the GUI and then File > Open.

Once opened, you will see:

[image]

Now to split the document up:

1. Select a page range from the page index on the left. You can use the usual range shortcuts:

   - Shift for range endpoint
   - Ctrl to select or unselect individual items
2. Ctrl + C or Right click > Copy
3. Ctrl + N or File > New to create a new document
4. Ctrl + V on new document to paste from the old document
5. No to "Do you want to scale the copied objects to fit the new page size?"
6. Shift + Delete or Right click > Delete Page to the pre-existing initial blank page from the new document
7. File > Export As > Export Directly as PDF.

   If you are doing this a lot, you might want to assign a keyboard shortcut to this option under Tools > Customize > Keyboard.

The PDF shown in the above examples is: [http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~perry/education/382v-s08/papers/raymond.pdf](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/%7Eperry/education/382v-s08/papers/raymond.pdf) which is a rendering of [The Cathedral and the Bazaar by Eric S. Raymond](The Cathedral and the Bazaar).

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, LibreOffice Draw 7.3.4.

Comment: Given the amount of [bugs I've found in LibreOffice](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/buglist.cgi?email1=dascalescu&emailreporter1=1&emailtype1=substring&list_id=915491&order=changeddate%20DESC%2C), including Draw's handling of PDFs, I wouldn't touch any important PDFs with it.

Comment: Tried it and result is poor. Formatting is not 100% correct and sequences of "it" and "ti" show up as blank. Still, was easy to try...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract pages in a WYSIWYG way, then `pdfarranger` offers a nice and simple GUI. It can also join PDFs, and you can rotate or crop pages.

[image: PSF Arranger]

Worked great on a TurboTax file, which [`pdfmod` couldn't open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf#comment2485063_221968).

The only (tiny) donwside was that it couldn't export some metadata and the table of contents was lost, but I verified that the exported selection included all pages I had selected, so the tool did its job.

Answer (score 1):

Apache PDFBox is open source Java tool for working with PDF documents. It comes with a command line tools that can split pages from pdf, among many others things ([see manual here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfsplit)).

To use it simply install the `pdfbox-app-2.?.?.jar` and execute a command like:

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.20.jar PDFSplit -startPage 1 -endPage 10 -outputPrefix ch1 book.pdf
```

Comment: This is excellent

Answer (score 1):

ThiagoPonte's Ghostscript answer is great for its portability, but it does not explain how to use a discontinuous page list, such as 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11. That is possible with [`-sPageList`](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPageList=2,6-9,11 -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

However I could not get it to work on older versions of Ghostscript, for which case, inspired by [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296238/ghostscript-spagelist-produces-stackunderflow-error-and-quits), I created this shell script that only relies on `-dFirstPage` and `-dLastPage`:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
if [ "$#" != 2 ] && [ "$#" != 3 ]; then
    >&2 echo "Usage: $0 pagelist infile [outfile]"
    exit 11
fi
range=$1
infile=$2
outfile=${3-"${2%pdf}"out.pdf}
set --
IFS=,
for i in $range; do
    set -- "$@" "-dFirstPage=${i%-*}" "-dLastPage=${i#*-}" "$infile"
done
gs -sOutputFile="$outfile" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "$@"
```

You can save it in a PATH directory such as `/usr/local/bin/`, make it executable with `chmod +x scriptname` and then just call

```
scriptname 2,6-9,11 in.pdf out.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have started to put together a [tool](https://github.com/mountbuild/mouse) to provide a simplified interface to common actions.

You can slice out a subset of a PDF like this:

```
$ npm install @mountbuild/mouse -g
$ mouse slice input.pdf -s 15 -e 25 -o output.pdf
```

This will create a new PDF for pages between and including 15 and 25.

If nothing else check out the source and see how to write your own script to do this in JavaScript.