# Extract page range from pdf

Tags: command-line, pdf

I want to extract the total page range of a pdf using using bash commands. Is it possible to do.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, by using the command-line `pdftk` utility. Please see the top answer on this askubuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf

Comment: The answer here allows converting selected pages into images : http://askubuntu.com/a/50180/295286

Comment: pdfinfo pdfname | grep Pages