# how to edit a .pdf file in kubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, pdf, text-editor, editing, konsole

How to edit .pdf files in Kubuntu 13.04 ? Is there any supported software like "Adobe Acrobat" with the help of which I could do editing ?

Comment: Searching for "how to edit pdf ubuntu", gave me the following page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend of two programs (both available in software center):

1. libreoffice-pdfimport - a libreoffice plugin that enable editing of PDF files. work better for editing text. it doesn't add itself to open with menu, and you have to open libreoffice-draw to open pdf documents with it.
2. xournal - can't edit text inside PDF documents, but has nice features for editing the pdf as an image.