# Canceling an area of a Pdf page with Ocular

Tags: okular

I'd like to cancel a specific area of a page; how can I do this with okular?

In Windows I used Acrobat and it allows me to do this by putting a white text box on the desired area.

Comment: Do you want to edit the pdf? In that case check this question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs

Comment: Hello @ArchismanPanigrahi I need to cancel an area with okular (not with other softwares), because I'd like to learn how to use okular

Comment: Okular is not a pdf editor. It is a reader with annotation tools. I am not sure what you meant by cancelling an area. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I mean that I'd like to replace an area (text, figure etc.) of a pdf page with a white area

Comment: I don't think Okular can do that. It is a PDF reader (like the old Adobe Reader). It cannot change a pdf. But you can try the softwares mentioned in the link I posted.

Comment: ok, thank you for your suggestion @ArchismanPanigrahi