# How can I convert a .tex file to a PDF via the command line?

Tags: pdf, latex

Is there a package that contains a TeX to PDF converter/renderer available on Ubuntu 12.04?

If not, can you recommend a tool for me to download from elsewhere that can do this that is simple to install?

Comment: Welcome Triss,  I investigated this a while back and I'm not sure there is a way via the command line.  I use Lyx.  You might find some useful information here though latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @StephenMyall: Lyx is _not_ a command line utility.

Comment: Im aware of that and thats why I commented rather than answer your question.  I wanted to let you know that I had looked for a command line utility before for this type of conversion with no luck.  I hope you have better luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as I know, you won't find a single standalone binary that will do this for you. The typical utility is called `pdflatex` and is part of the TeX Live package. It's in the repositories, so simply opening the terminal and typing the below will install `pdflatex` and lots of other essential TeX stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Comment: For people who see this QnA, do visit https://tex.stackexchange.com and a sample pdf question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149649/a-basic-question-about-raw-pdf-file-output-by-pdftex

Comment: The difficulty with this answer is that it doesn't actually tell the asker how to use the pdflatex utility to make the conversion on the command line. Since that was the question, this doesn't provide a full answer. (Some of us may be able to just read man pages, but for command-line novices who might read this some more explanation is important.)

Comment: You may also need `sudo apt install texinfo`. I did.

Answer (score 50):

At the command line, first install the texlive package if it isn't already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

Then use the pdflatex utility to convert the file like this:

```
pdftex /path/to/myfile.tex
```

The path /path/to/myfile.tex is, of course, an example path. You would put the path to your own file on your system.

Notice that although the utility is called pdflatex you execute it with the command *pdftex* (without the *la*).

There are several settings that you can read about in the help for pdflatex:

```
pdflatex --help
```

The setting I use the most is the one to generate the pdf in a different directory:

```
pdflatex --output-directory=../otherdir /path/to/myfile.tex
```

The pdflatex utility is also interactive, so that if you forget to supply necessary information it will prompt you to enter it before converting the file.

Comment: pdftex and pdflatex don't seem to be the same thing. pdflatex supports LaTeX but pdftex doesn't (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258622)

Comment: I support @bmaupin's comment. TeX and LaTeX are not the same. If you force me to answer I had to make an educated guess that LaTeX is a 'superset' of TeX. Once aware it's trivial to switch between an e.g. wrongly `pdftex file.tex` to `pdflatex` but for the uninitiated it might be confusing as you casually switch from the former to the latter in your answer.

Comment: Upvoted. I added a few extras to install [in my new answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473017/327339), too.

Comment: Big update: you may need to use `pdflatex` instead of `pdftex`. I've described the differences now [in my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473017/327339).

Answer (score 4):

You should try [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber). It is a command-line tool to handle all the tasks associated with compiling TeX documents into *pdf*, *dvi*, etc.

Comment: rubber --pdf file.tex

Answer (score 3):

### Install `texlive` and all the extras: how to convert a .tex file to a PDF (TeX to PDF, and [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) to PDF)

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2.*

In addition to the main `texlive` program, there are some extras and extra fonts and things you might want too. So, I've gathered the commands from this tutorial ([Linux Hint: How Do I Convert a .tex Latex File to PDF in Linux?](https://linuxhint.com/convert-tex-latex-file-to-pdf/)) and placed them all below:

### 1. Install `texlive`

```bash
sudo apt update

# (copy and paste and run this whole block of lines at once)
sudo apt install -y \
    texlive \
    texinfo \
    texlive-fonts-recommended \
    texlive-fonts-extra \
    texlive-latex-extra
```

### 2. Use it: produce file.pdf from file.tex

```bash
# 1: for a plain TeX format .tex file
pdftex my_TeX_file.tex

# 2: for a LaTeX format .tex file
pdflatex my_LaTeX_file.tex
```

From `man pdftex` (emphasis added):

> The  typical  use of pdfTeX is with a pregenerated formats for which PDF output has been enabled.  The `pdftex` command uses the equivalent of the **plain TeX format**, and the `pdflatex` command uses the equivalent of the **LaTeX format**.

### More details, and `! Undefined control sequence.` errors

Notice that you may need to use `pdflatex` above, *not* `pdftex`. That's because `pdftex` is for plain TeX format, whereas `pdflatex` is for LaTeX format. `pdftex` is more limited and doesn't process LaTeX packages at all, resulting in bad results. See here: [TEX Stack Exchange: "Undefined control sequence" at beginning of any simple document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258622/168682).

If your .tex document has any `\documentclass{}` or `\usepackage{}` calls at all, for instance, then it is LaTeX format, and you'll have to use a tool such as `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or `lualatex` instead of `pdftex`. `pdflatex` works very well for me.

The errors I see when I mistakenly try to process a LaTeX format document using `pdftex` look like this, for instance:

```bash
makani$ pdftex documentation/control/aero/aero_spec.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./documentation/control/aero/aero_spec.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  [11pt]{amsart}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               {geometry}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \geometry
             {letterpaper}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \usepackage
               {graphicx}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \usepackage
               {amssymb}
?
```

To find the solution at the link above, I used this Google search: [pdftex Undefined control sequence.](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdftex+Undefined+control+sequence.&oq=pdftex+Undefined+control+sequence.&aqs=chrome..69i57.1918j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

### Full demo

Here's a full demo of an online LaTeX `.tex` file you can process. It works very well.

We will convert this LaTeX file to a PDF: https://github.com/google/makani/blob/master/documentation/control/aero/aero_spec.tex. This is from the Google "Makani" kite/tethered aircraft wind power generation project.

```bash
# download this LaTeX file
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/makani/master/documentation/control/aero/aero_spec.tex
# convert it to a PDF
pdflatex aero_spec.tex
```

Now, manually open up `aero_spec.pdf` in your favorite PDF viewer, such as [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/), which allows you to highlight, underline, write notes, etc, in the PDF.

Here's what the generated PDF looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 13.10 I suggest you use [texlive-full](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). It worked for me  but I'm non experienced user (:-)

To install it, open a terminal window and type or copy/paste:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: Does this still apply for 15.x?

Comment: *Better*? **No**. `texlive-full` is just a huge archive that include lots of Latex related packages, including `texlive` itself (which in fact is shorthand for `texlive-base`). By installing `texlive-full` you will get lots of things you probably will never use, like `texlive-lang-czechslovak`.