# PDF reader with Highlighting support and save the file

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, annotation, adobe-acrobat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)

I am missing the feature of Highlighting the PDF file directly from reader and saving the changes in the file. This is a feature of Adobe Acrobat Reader *(The commercial one)*.

I have tried Okular, but it does not save the changes in the file. **So please don't comment this question as an exact duplicate of [this question "How can I highlight PDF"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-pdfs)**.

I want a name of a pdf reader which is equivalent to Adobe Acrobat Reader *(In the functionality of hightlighting pdf and saving the highlighted file also in pdf)*.

I have tried, xournal and okular. xournal does not do the right thing, very slow. and okular can highlight, but has no option of saving the the file as PDF.