# Why i cannot comment with my Acrobat reader 9.5.1?

Tags: adobe-reader

I downloaded Adobe acrobat 9.5.1 reader software package from Adobe's site. The .deb extension. But i cannot see the comment menu under the tools, in any pdf file that i am trying to comment

Comment: Ok actually i didn't manage to install 9.5.1 because the version is for i386 and mine is 64-bit processor so i realized that i had an old version There is no 64bit version of Acrobat fr Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because Adobe Reader 9 does not have commenting features :)

Adobe Reader XI has commenting and highlighting:

> Can I use Reader XI to add comments and highlights to a PDF file?
>
> Reader XI is the first version of Reader that enables users to annotate PDF documents using a full set of commenting and markup tools, including sticky notes, a freehand drawing tool, and typewriter, highlight, underline, and strikethrough tools. You can also use Reader XI to participate in shared document reviews, with team members seeing and building on each other’s comments to speed up review cycles.

Source: http://www.adobe.com/products/reader/faq.html

Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230629/free-pdf-reader-that-supports-taking-notes-and-bookmarks/230634#230634) for pdf commenting.

Comment: there is no supported version for Ubuntu for XI!

Comment: there are alternatives to Adobe Reader XI

Comment: Alternatives is another story.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, try opening your PDF in another program! I'm using Mendeley because it allows highlighting and notes. Seems to work with any PDF, no matter what the properties of the PDF are or what operating system(s) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any native Linux pdf reader capable of annotations.

My solution was to install wine1.5 and install Foxit Reader 5 for Windows (not the version they have for linux which is outdated).

Add the wine ppa: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

Next type: `sudo apt-get update`
Followed by `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Then download the Foxit reader for windows installer and run it.

If you want to have the Foxit icon instead of the wine icon in the launcher, then see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/95404/27968).

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

One can also try Okular. It is available in the Ubuntu Software Centre. One can easily highlight and make notes. The changes made to the pdf document is preserved when viewed in other pdf readers ( I tried to read the modified document in my phone using Adobe Acrobat Reader). It also works well with Document Viewer which is a default pdf reader in Ubuntu. Hope this helps.