# Install FoxitReader without using Wine

Tags: pdf

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

I recently came to know that **FoxitReader** Ubuntu version has been released. But I am unable to install it using the instructions given in its manual(check this [link](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitReader1.1ForLinux_Manual.pdf)).

When I enter this command:`sudo dpkg -i FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb`, I get the following:

> (Reading database ... 341123 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb ...
>   Unpacking foxitreader (1.1-0) over (1.1-0) ...
>   Setting up foxitreader (1.1-0) ...
>   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
>   Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
>   Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...

Please help me to install it if someone has done it successfully.

Comment: @Helio i just edited my question. please check it.

Comment: @Helio but I don't see FoxitReader....I don't think it is installed.

Comment: @Helio how to run it from terminal?...open Foxitreader?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22404/discussion-between-sssss-and-helio).

Comment: Type `FoxitReader` on the terminal (keep in mind that contains caps)

Comment: @Helio Yeaa i did exactly like tht.....but nothing happened

Comment: Please, put a screenshot of the terminal.

Comment: Your output doesn't seem to contain an error. I've done pretty much the same process as Ravan's answer, and I know that FoxitReader installed with .run package , creates desktop shortcut. What else it does is that it installs itself in the same directory where you run the installation. So if you run installation of  that `*.deb` file in Downloads folder, check that Downloads folder, probably it has directory for FoxitReader.  I cannot see how Foxit developers would make the two installations behave differently for the same software

Comment: In fact , on my system I ran installation in my homefolder. Now I have the actual executable in `/home/serg/FoxitSoftware/FoxitReader/FoxitReader.sh`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**September 15, 2015**,Foxit Reader is now available for Ubuntu ,

1.Go to official site  [foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/)

Click on download button and select Linux (either 32 or 64 bit)

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Now Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
ls    
tar -xzvf FoxitReader1.00.0909_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz
chmod +x FoxitReader.enu.setup.1.0.0.0909.run
./FoxitReader.enu.setup.1.0.0.0909.run
```

**Note** While running *chmod* command I got *syntax error near unexpected token `('* error.I re-named the extracted file then executed the command.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

(All screen-shots are from my system @Ravan )

Comment: Exactly the same steps I did on my Deepin virtual machine :) Good job !

Comment: There is a bug in foxit website but there is direct link:  http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/en_us/FoxitReader1.10.0225_Server_x64_enu_Setup.run.tar.gz

Comment: Not so easy to install (for me at least) but looks veeeery cool. Thanks!

Comment: Even not advertised, you can add custom stamps if you copy your stamp as pdf into the stamp folder of your installation directory (e.g. ~/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/stamps/en-US/Sign Here)

Comment: you can refer to file using quotation marks, eg.: sudo ./'FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.4.0911(r057d814).x64.run'

Comment: This worked in ubuntu 18. I followed the exact steps specified.

Comment: Foxit Reader just keeps hanging on Ubuntu 20.04 as I try to open a pdf on an external hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I've used to install it on my 64bit system.

To install FoxitReader on Ubuntu 64bit, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/enu/FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb
```

I'm running Xubuntu, and it shows in the menu.  See image below.

[image]

Here it is on Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

<sup>Source for the commands:[LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-foxit-reader-1-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/)</sup>

Comment: Note that the `.deb` file above dates back to 2013 while the file directly available from the Foxit website is from 2016. (Source: Timestamps on http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/)

Answer (score 0):

I just extracted to my Downloads file, renamed the file to `Foxit.run` and performed the commands below:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt clean

sudo apt autoremove

cd /home/<my_user_name>/Downloads
```

Then I ran it:

```
./Foxit.run
```

and install proceeded flawlessly.

much simpler.