# How to install Adobe Acrobat Reader DC in Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe

How to install the latest version (Acrobat DC) in Ubuntu?

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602861/install-foxitreader-without-using-wine/679213#679213)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, exactly because there is no Ubuntu version for Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, there is a `.run` file for the Foxit reader for Linux.

However you should read [How to Install Software when you're a future ex-Windows user **first**](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) as `.run` files are more difficult to remove then `.deb` files.

If you still want to go ahead: [FoxIt downloads page](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/)

Comment: you can  provide this link;[install-foxitreader-without-using-wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602861/install-foxitreader-without-using-wine/679213#679213)..;P

Comment: @Ravan: I voted to duplicate to yours instead!  (but still got an upvote for mine today!  **;-)**

Comment: I too give one today :p

Answer (score 10):

There is no Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Linux / Unix version available.
So unfortunately you only can install the latest supported version 9.

If you alternatively want to install the older version of Adobe Reader,
follow this link already provided by @DevRobot under your question :

[How do I install Adobe Acrobat Reader deb package downloaded from Adobe website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89127/how-do-i-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-deb-package-downloaded-from-adobe-website)

Comment: There is a unix version of Foxit Reader!  **;-)**