# Comment & Highlight the PDF & DJVU files?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, software-sources, document, djvu

I have just started working with Ubuntu.

My work includes a lot of books that to be read. Hence while reading, I need to --comment & `highlight` the characters in the form of PDF & DJVU file.

I have installed **`Document Viewer`** and **`qpdfviewer`**. But both of these softwares do not have this option.

I can't find any other in `Ubuntu software updater`. So Please suggest me some softwares according to my needs.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ? @seeking_infinity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can comment in **Document Viewer**(or **evince**), but I didn't find any entries for highlighting.
Here is how to add a comment in **Document Viewer**(or *annotation*):

In the **Document Viewer**, you may have a side pane, or you can manually open it by pressing  <kbd>F9</kbd>

In the **Side Pane**, there is a few options on the top, just like this:

[image: Side pane top]

Then you can select the option of *Annotations*, as shown in the picture. Then select the *Add* button.

[image]

Click on the Pen button to add one.

[image: Pen]

It will pop out a little white cross, click on anywhere on the document to start comment, or add an *Annotation*.

For the **Highlighting** function, you need to ask other people.

Comment: Thank you. Its working in a PDF file . I forgot to mention in my question, that I need the same for DJVU files as well. Annotations is not working there.

Comment: Oh, sorry, but I am not familiar with DJVU files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Xournal` - Ubuntu Apps

Xournal is a GTK+ application for notetaking, sketching and keeping a journal using a stylus. It can also be used to add annotations to PDF files.

[image: Xournal]

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xournal
```

Optional, to remove Xournal, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove xournal
```

[DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) which is an implementation of DjVu, including viewers, browser plugins, decoders, simple encoders, and utilities.

[image: DjVuLibre]

[Okular](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/okular/) is a universal document viewer with support for advanced document features, such as highlights,annotations, forms, and embedded files.

[image: Okular]

To View djvu files using Okular :

```
apt-get install okular-extra-backends
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Its working for PDF files. Can you suggest the same for DJVU files?

Comment: Thank you @sridhar. Okular has a variety of options which match my requirements.

Comment: okular saves djvu annotations internally, meaning that if I open annotated djvu with other viewers except for okular I won't see the annotations.