# Highlight text in CHM files

Tags: 14.04, text, adobe-reader, chm

I have few [chm files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) and i'm using [xchm reader](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xchm/) as the tool. but i need to highlight some important points in the documents. is there is any possible plugin for xchm or any special chm readers available for Ubuntu that can highlight text..?

Answer (score 0):

I know of no CHM viewer who can.

You could convert the `chm` document into a `pdf` and use an annotation tool for `pdf` files: [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1529/367165)

To convert the `chm` file, install `chm2pdf`

```
sudo apt-get install chm2pdf
```

and create a `pdf`, eg:

```
chm2pdf --book yourfile.chm
```

Comment: Sorry A.B this not what i'm looking for.  Because CHM files it self have some spacial attributes that a pdf don't have . like i can change the font and bold some important points in pdf its not possible . so i don't want to change it to pdf. Anyway thanks.