# Mark area on PDF file

Tags: pdf

I received a mail with a PDF attachment. I need to pass the 20 pages long PDF to a group of people.

This group of people should focus on a part on page 3. I would like to mark this part with a red square, to make it easy for the people to find the important information.

How can I do this?

I use the default Ubuntu LTS (14.04).

**Update**: I don't want to annotate text like in other questions. I want to draw a colored rectangle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I highlight or annotate PDFs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1529/how-can-i-highlight-or-annotate-pdfs)

Comment: My use case is a bit different. I don't want to annotate with text, I want to draw a rectangle. But the result is the same: There is no software for ubuntu which helps. Sad.

Comment: You can highlight using okular, last I checked. I think it's added more graphical annotation options since. Sad that you didn't even try.

Comment: I just tried `qpdfview` from the above answers link, for highlighting, and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The program `okular` can do it. But you need to use "save as" to write the annotations to a new pdf.

Quoting the FAQ: https://okular.kde.org/faq.php#addedannotationsinpdf

> Why the newly added annotations are not in my PDF document?
>
> By default, Okular saves annotations in the local data directory for
>   each user. Since KDE 4.9, it's optionally possible to store them
>   directly in a PDF file by choosing "File -> Save As...", so they can
>   be seen in other PDF viewers.

Comment: I don't see how okular can add a rectangle to a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The xournal application allows you to add draw lines (straight and free-hand).

You can also add text and highlighter parts of your PDF.

You install it by calling `sudo apt-get install xournal`