# Document viewer doesn't have add annotation enable for pdf

Tags: xubuntu, pdf, evince, annotation

I have a vmware setup with Xubuntu and I have found myself not going back to OSX. Now I'm trying to learn a bit more about the ecosystem and how to set things that accommodate my needs.
In my working environment, I read pdfs' often. I'm utilizing Document Viewer to read. However, I don't see the `Add Annotations` feature in the app. How I can enable this feature?

[image]

Comment: For the moment I install `Okular` and it is doing the job. However, I would like to learn how to fix `Document Viewer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the toolbar from left, then locate the rightmost icon.

Click the icon (pencil icon in your screenshot), then another toolbar will appear and will show two more icons for adding "text annotation" and "highlight annotation".

[image: Using annotation in Evince 3.18.2-1ubuntu4]

Evince Document Viewer has slightly different user interface, depending on which [available package of Evince](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=evince&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in use. The annotation icon is located either in the toolbar menu (newer version, above) or the sidebar menu (older version, below).

[image: Using annotation in Evince 3.10.3-0ubuntu10]

I have tested and confirmed the annotated PDF file that has been created in the newer version can be opened and seen similarly in the older version. However:

- text that has been added to any highlight annotation will neither be viewable nor editable
- older version of Evince allows to add and modify "text annotation", but can't remove it
- the "highlight annotation" feature is unavailable for older version of Evince, which is `3.10.3-0ubuntu10` in Xubuntu Trusty (14.04)

Compare above screenshots and notice some differences.

**TL;DR** The annotation icon is already there. Similarly noted in [this canonical answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/667017/37165).