# How to "reply to comments" on a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I'm working on a permit application for some project, and the city has sent me a PDF and asked me to reply to the comments.

I don't seem to find any comments or "reply" buttons anywhere, regardless of whether I use the basic document viewer, or even Okular. Normally, editable PDF forms are easily savable, but this is being problematic.

The instructions they provide, for context:

`"This can be accomplished by using the “Reply” function in Bluebeam or in the Comment panel of Adobe Acrobat."`

Can someone please guide me as to how to do the thing the previous paragraph wants me to do, assuming I'm running Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I think ["comments" may be called differently](https://askubuntu.com/q/1529/925128) in Evince or Okular. Anyway, try to test by opening the pdf in Chrome/Chromium or Firefox. I would also try Okular but that comes with a lot of dependencies in Ubuntu/Gnome, so unless you are in Kubuntu or Lubuntu I recommend to try Master PDF Editor. Foxreader can also be installed or used as appimage. Old version of Adobe Reader [seems still available](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux) (haven't tested), or new ones can be used with Wine.

Comment: Maybe related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265845/pdf-reader-that-supports-xfa-forms-while-adobe-reader-for-linux-is-not-supporte

Comment: Ok, I think Master PDF Editor knows how to do it, at least I got part-way there. Will update with instructions once I confirm it does what I need it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master PDF Editor seems to do the trick.

- Install Master PDF Editor (have to download the .deb and install)
- Open the doc with Master PDF Editor
- Click on the comment
- Click the icon that looks like a "talk bubble" (as opposed to the color selection).
- From within the comment, click "Options" on the right
- Click on "Reply" to leave a reply

It doesn't look like there's a "save comment" type of option, so just leave the textbox open with your comment and when you save the doc, it will save your latest comment.